# Opinionated programming answers are prohibited?

Tags: discussion

It has been a while since I asked a question on Stack Overflow.  The most recent question I asked was put on hold for being off-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23380294/366309.

In defense of the question, I think that it's likely some expert programmer who works with Vim for 14 hours a day could have come across this problem.  Or someone with 10,000 hours of regex experience could help out.  The question title, with its tags, clearly puts it in context when listed on the homepage.

To be honest, I was offended and surprised that the Stack Overflow community no longer considers questions about Vimscript, or even customizing programming tools (in the form of asking for plugin recommendations), as programming-related.  The elitist feel of the sanction was a turn-off.  Really, gods of Silicon Valley?

But my main beef with the community downvote was this:

[image]

My big question is: **Are we computers whose resolution is limited to the number of bits, or humans who have an infinite resolution for representing knowledge and experience?**

Or, if you don't get it, **Do you really expect the human community to provide a definitive non-opinionated 64-bit answer for every question?**

Up until about a year ago, I was an active user on Stack Overflow while getting up to speed with Python.  The plugin and package recommendations, together with their **OPINIONS**, has helped me a lot with making choices.

For the good of the community, lift this restriction on opinionated answers.  Instead, encourage users to downvote flaming rants to oblivion.

Comment: Well, we certainly don't have _infinite_ capacity. My brain is only about a liter and a quarter in volume.

Comment: It seems I have returned to an entirely different community than I have left about a year ago.

Comment: For the good of the community, this won't change. Links disappear, leaving answers that contain them meaningless and devoid of content. You want links, use Google and Bing - their very existence is based on searching for things and returning lists of links to the search results. Opinions are just that - **personal** opinions, and there could be a thousand different ones on any given topic, making 999 of those useless to the person asking the question (and all related to products/libraries that may not exist next week).

Comment: @KenWhite you have a point there. I also mentioned that those kinds of answers have helped me tremendously, and I like to think that others also have that experience. Yes, Google and Bing exist, but only for those who know the name for what they are searching. Know that man started grunting before he developed intelligible language. For us less-intelligible folks, we struggle to describe to computers what we are looking for. If you're worried about link-only answers, isn't there a community guideline to describe what you are linking? Yes, links appear and disappear, because the Internet ...

Comment: It's been quite some time since [resource requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128158/where-should-looking-for-resources-questions-go) were _not_ verboten; I'm not sure you've actually been an SO member that long. I certainly haven't. They're closely related to [the shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), identified in 2010.

Comment: ... is primarily human and it evolves.

Comment: @Kit: But SO is not a software/tool/library/resource recommendations site. It's a **programming** site. Crawl out of the "somebody tell me what to do" stage of evolution, and learn to do your own research. If I want an IDE to use to develop in a new language, I can find a list of them via Google, read reviews, download trials, and see which one works for me. If you narrow down a list of products you're considering to a couple of choices, and then ask **specific** questions about feature differences/support, we can help. Shopping lists are inappropriate here, and have been for several years.

Comment: I don't think your question was off topic (it would have been useful to show effort in the form of something you tried in vimscript, but I wouldn't close for that, and I think it was right to be reopened). However, statements like "elitist", "gods of Silicon Valley?", and "Are we computers..." were definitely not the right way to approach the community about it.

Comment: Your question involves both the “vim” and “vimscript” tags. I follow those a bit and I sadly I [don’t think](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21318312/758011) this is an unfrequent occurrence with either.

Comment: I fail to see how this question is any different than any of the thousands of other "How do I do X" questions that show no research or even an attempt by the OP to solve the problem on their own which we close every day.

Comment: @KenWhite, certainly shopping lists (many of them in the form of community wikis) of popular Python packages to solve a particular problem were how I got better with Python.  That was around 2011.  A certain openness to the question helps, and given the noobish question I just asked, I felt that being too specific might exclude hidden gems from being contributed as answers.  You'll know from my question history that I do diligent research before posting and that I'm not lazy.  I just turned into a grunting Neanderthal when it came to this case of Vimscript.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, because computers cannot form an opinion.  This prohibition of opinionated (but technically informed and non-inflammatory) answers might as well tell the community members to morph into computers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I said _resolution_ (many ways to represent a small or big amount of knowledge, and that includes opinions), not _capacity_ (for air in my head, if that is what you were referring to).  But that is nitpicking.  Let's move on.

Comment: 64 bit answer - it's 8 ASCII characters, even less with Unicode. It's too short even for a comment. But your question title doesn't match your body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why your question was closed. It doesn't meet *any* of our criteria for closure.

It is, however, poorly researched, and downvotes would be appropriate.

I've re-opened your question and left a comment as to why I re-opened it.

Now on to this meta post:

> To be honest, I was offended and surprised that the Stack Overflow community no longer considers questions about Vimscript, or even customizing programming tools (in the form of asking for plugin recommendations), as programming-related. The elitist feel of the sanction was a turn-off. Really, gods of Silicon Valley?

None of that is warranted, no matter your level of frustration.  Sometimes on-topic questions get closed; but the way to ensure that they stay closed is to then make fun of the very people who closed it.

The proper way to handle closure is to do one of the following (usually in this order):

- Leave a comment asking how you can improve your question
- Edit your question to take out anything that may conflict with the close reason
- Open a meta post that lays out your question, why it's on topic, and what you can do to improve it (without name calling, preferably).

Asking for an offsite resource is off topic, for many reasons (what follows is just a few enumerated reasons, and isn't meant to be exhaustive):

- Stirs up opinions
- Becomes a list of things that is rarely maintained (There are a few counter examples; and even fewer good counter examples)
- Which one is 'correct'?

In your case, you didn't ask for an offsite resource; you just needed some code.  However, since you didn't do any research, or show people what you've tried, there's no way to know what issues you're having.

What makes it worse is that learning to program Vim through VimScript is probably trivial; but given that you haven't told us what your level of knowledge is, there's no way to know if you could even apply an answer given to you (we used to have a close reason for that, "minimal understanding").

There are a subset of community members who close questions because the OP hasn't demonstrated any research ability, but as of yet that viewpoint hasn't prevailed.

Comment: "It doesn't meet any of our criteria for closure." - It would appear every mod of this site has a different opinion on this, which is *very* frustrating from the standpoint of those of us trying to be good citizens. In the past "Too Localized" or "Not Demonstrating Sufficient Effort" would have been valid close reasons. Now we're told (by some mods) that "Unclear what you're asking" is the analogous close reason to those (which, IMHO, it isn't because that's not how its worded). The discussion [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252534/302916) talking about the close reasons, for example.

Comment: I've posed a [new question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) looking for clarity on this. As someone who donates their time *only* to answer questions here and to moderate (as a high-rep user) I think this deserves attention.

Comment: The question is again put on hold.

Comment: @BrianRoach If you can show me public statements by other moderators where they differ on this, I'd be glad to take a look. However, I can't find a single close reason that meets what you're looking for. We can't just make up close reasons because we don't like a question -- that's what downvoting is for.  "Not demonstrating sufficient effort" *has never been* a close reason. Never.

Comment: Quoting your comment on the question, `The OP hasn't asked for their code to be debugged (a problem to be fixed), they're asking for code to do something in VimScript.` - Exactly! This is NOT a question, it is just a **task** disguised as a question. I believe Shog9 stated in a related discussion that when OP just drops a task on SO and asks us to do all of it, it should be considered too broad.

Comment: @l4mpi See my answer here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x/253096#253096 Essentially we've always allowed these sorts of questions, the delimiter is How much we'd need to communicate to implement what the OP wants? If it takes a book, it's too broad. If it's only a few paragraphs, it's not.

Comment: The first answer to the SO question has certainly opened new avenues for research and exploration.  If I had been more specific, it may not have been offered as a possible solution.  Or quite possibly, in an attempt to be more specific, I'd be at a loss for words due to my lack of understanding of Vimscript, further muddling the question.

Comment: "Which one is correct?" The insistence for a definitive answer to every question was what triggered my comparison to computers. Some questions have multiple correct answers. One of them is the most correct for the OP. Others are more correct for later visitors to the page. Opinions help in choosing which one works better for the reader. I used to see SO as a place where I can find answers to guide further questions. Right now it seems that it is no longer the case. For me, it is sad.

Comment: @Kit Our format isn't good for opinions. It's just a artifact of how we do.

Comment: Not in my experience. That may have been triggered by inflammatory opinions, which I haven't come across when I was active during my first few years on the site.