# What's the appropriate new/current close reason for "How do I do X?"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

A recent [question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253055/opinionated-programming-answers-are-prohibited) from a user asking about why their question was closed resulted in it not only being re-opened by a mod, but that mod answering with:

> I'm not sure why your question was closed. It doesn't meet any of our criteria for closure.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380294/how-do-i-highlight-parentheses-whenever-the-cursor-is-inside) was "How do I do X?" where `X` involved writing some code. (the initial reason it was closed, apparently, was people thinking they were looking for a vi/vim plugin, but that is outside the scope of this question)

My question is very simple: **Do we no longer have a valid close reason for "How do I do X?" where the OP has done no research, no code, and has provided no evidence that they have tried anything themselves?**

As I commented on the aforementioned thread, other mods have said "Unclear what you're asking" close reason is analogous to our old (evil/mean/hurting people's feelings) "Too Localized" or (**edit**: I had this one wrong) "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" close reasons. In which case the question **certainly** has a valid close reason, contrary to what is being stated.

I actually disagree based on the *that close reason's text* as it in no way would apply:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

It's certainly clear what the OP's problem is, and what they are asking; they want someone to tell them how to do it / write the code for them.

This similarly applies to any other "Tell me how to do X" question, or homework code dump where the user says "I'm trying to do X, here's my 200 lines of code, tell me how to fix it" where there's *literally* nothing in that code dump that attempts to do what they're asking.

Comment: Discussion that may interest readers of this question: [How does "proof of effort" make a question better?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179035)

Comment: The ones I despise have an additional facet: they dump their data into the question expecting the community to fulfill their work order. It shows utter contempt for the community.

Answer (score 73):

There has never been a valid close reason for someone who didn't exhibit any research effort.

Of course, there has always been an avenue to address those types of question: **Downvote**.

[image: downvote questions that don't have research]

We do have close reasons for broadness -- that is, if a subject would be way too broad to answer in a few paragraphs.

That can *sometimes* apply to "How do I do X?" questions:

- How do I write a game engine in XNA?
- How do I write my own OAuth Provider?
- How do I create a facebook clone?

But othertimes, It can't:

- [Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time) (note, this is post number #11 on Stack Overflow)
- [Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)
- [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)

Overall, there isn't and never has been a close reason simply for a lazy person.  If you'd like to propose one, I suggest asking a new meta question and making it a feature request.

Don't interpret this answer as my stance on such questions, just that it's my duty to enforce our standards. If you want to change those standards, a meta [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) question is the way to do it.

Comment: I think [Recent changes to close reasons on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow) is good read for close voters

Comment: "There has never been a valid close reason for someone who didn't exhibit any research effort" ??? I thought that some version of "what have you tried" was frequently asked in the comments, and that there used to be a specific language like this (in the "minimal understanding" reason, I believe. Hard to find now that it's gone:) _"Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."_ I think that counts as "show (research) effort". At least "let me google that for you" has frequently been used in conjunction with a flurry of downvotes...

Comment: "Minimal understanding" was taken away because it was misinterpreted as "minimal effort". Its intended meaning was to make sure the OP had enough grasp of the fundamentals that a solution would be useful and wouldn't cause a series of "Why?" reminiscient of a nine-year old asking about why the sky is blue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, understanding takes effort. Asking "How do I calculate relative time?" is a lack of understanding (likely because of lack of effort, not a natural handicap).

Comment: @PaulDraper Understanding does take effort; but it's not understanding that makes me ask the question on Stack Overflow: I conceptually understand the problem, and given enough time, I could make a solution. Stack Overflow allows me to ask the question; and someone with a greater understanding (or ability) is able to whip up an answer in a fraction of the time it'd take me. That's why Stack Overflow is useful and popular. That's why that question should stay around -- it has value, even though the OP didn't show any effort.

Comment: `That's why Stack Overflow is useful and popular.` <--for people to ask questions. But giving people teh codez is, I suspect, not at all the driving factor for people actually *answering* questions.

Comment: Err, maybe I'm missing something, but all of those example questions are *really* old. Our standards for question quality have changed since then. Or have we again reverted back to what was permissible in 2009?

Comment: @George, we seem to have a problem here, with users interpreting your (and Robert's) answer as proof you're not willing to fix the current situation. I believe that's false, but maybe if you emphasized your last paragraph it would help, as I think the takeaway here is *there is no such close reason yet, if you want one,* ***propose one***.

Comment: @CodyGray Close reason wise; we've never needed to 'revert' because the close reasons are what they are, and "Lack of Effort" has never been among the close reasons.  One of the reasons the short lived "minimal understanding" was scrapped was because people were incorrectly interpreting it as a "lack of effort" close reason.

Comment: A question that has no research effort (vote -1) can still be valuable if enough people find it useful (vote +1). To me, this is fine for the linked questions in this answer, where people are wanting to learn - meaning they are likely taking the information from these posts and applying it to varying situations. Where this seems to not work is when somebody is not interested in learning, but just wants to copy-paste code to get it working for their one instance. I think it is the lack of wanting to actually learn from their question which makes it feel like they are taking advantage of users.

Comment: When is it going to dawn on the powers-that-be that help vampires **don't care about down-votes**. Swift question closure is what stops them. I can create an account today, ask a crap "Gimmez the codez" question, take my 11 downvotes and probably still get a workable answer. And this has helped no-one but me.

Comment: @duncan Downvoting counts towards a question ban. They can't ask questions if they are banned.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker True, but how many of these characters hang around and try and nurture a SO account? I would wager a fair percentage are one-question wonders.

Answer (score 13):

There was never a valid close reason for "insufficient research" or "insufficient effort," and there still isn't one.

If the OP is asking for too much, i.e. a good answer (one that the op would understand) would fill the better part of a book chapter, then close as too broad.  Otherwise, just answer the question, if you feel inclined to do so.

Comment: Oh wait ... you're right. Instead of answering the question you choose to pick on what I stated as previous close reasons. What I was actually thinking about was "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" ... I'll edit.

Comment: But don't miss the opportunity to write your answer in a "which way" book format. "Do you handle cleaning up stale locks with Perl? Turn to question 193934. Do you write an auto purging file system in C++? Turn to question 666" (I kid, I kid, I kid)

Comment: That close reason never meant "minimal effort". Its abuse as such is what caused its removal.

Comment: So, What you're stating **as an authoritative answer (because you're a moderator) regarding what is and isn't a valid question on StackOverflow**, is that is someone posts "How do I do X", with nothing else, that's now a valid question? Because if it is, I'm done. Seriously. I fail to see how that is in any way a valid question as per the guidelines or how it serves anyone.

Comment: @BrianRoach you can't generalize the "How do I do X" questions. "How do I write a game engine" would still be off-topic for example. But as "Too broad".

Comment: @Bart I fail to see how this question is ambiguous in any way. "How do I do X?". Where X is *anything*, and nothing else is provided in the Q; no research (e.g. "I looked at X,Y,Z and I don't see how that helps","I've read the docs and I don't understand Y", etc), and no code.

Comment: @BrianRoach: It is a valid and welcome question according to the powers that be -- and it has been at least since the "too localized" and "minimal effort" close reasons disappeared. And possibly earlier, if Robert is anything to go by. Sucks, but true.

Comment: @BrianRoach my understanding (it's probably wrong) is that we're just supposed to "downvote and move on" with such questions; the question-ban algorithm will see to it that persistent askers of such questions will be question-banned.

Comment: @Denis If that's the case then really this place is truly now "Experts Exchange II". Unless I see something change in the near future I'm just going to edit my profile the way [BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) has.

Comment: @BrianRoach: No need to edit your profile, just do it. I do the same, and we're certainly not the only ones if that thread on 30k+ users is anything to go by. I wish it would change, hence my returning to meta in light of recent threads. But I doubt it will.

Comment: @AakashM So, there's *some* relief there, especially since Tim Post (SO dev) posted about improving that algo/system. But of course it doesn't solve the problem of repwhores upvoting crap questions and answering them :(

Comment: I can't help but notice ::crickets:: from my comment above calling out for an authoritative answer to my *actual* question rather than the  derailment that is this "answer".

Comment: @BrianRoach `"How do I do X?". Where X is anything, and nothing else is provided in the Q` - if it's something simple it's bound to be a duplicate, complex then too broad.

Comment: @OGHaza No, seriously, it's not "too broad" either, because 9x out of 10 it's something trivial that there is an exact answer that covers it. See the point of this Q - the mod said "It doesn't meet any of our criteria for closure" - that would include "too broad". And the whole "it's a dup" debate is raging as well because apparently unless the question is an *exact duplicate*, down to the last detail, marking it as such and pointing to a Q/A that a competent person could derive the solution from isn't acceptable as well.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so if the community wants a "minimal effort" close reason, why not provide one?

Comment: @Brian Just my opinion, you can handle them how you like. Note that I never said something trivial would be too broad. You can literally close a question for any reason you like, as long as 4 other people agree, if the mods disagree then so be it, if it's a terrible question it's highly unlikely they're going to overrule the opinion of the community.

Comment: @BrianRoach Short, to the point "how do I do x" questions can often be a very useful resource. I don't see that questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/92082/73226) would be improved by adding additional information.

Comment: @MartinSmith I'd say the question seems useless as you can (and should) just look up the documentation of the `ALTER TABLE` statement. Otherwise, I can think of a few hundred questions to ask covering every aspect of every SQL statement, e.g. "How do I drop a column", "How do I rename a column", "How do I create a table", "How do I delete a table", "How do I rename a table", "How do I truncate a table", "How do I insert a row", "How do I update a row", "How do I update a column in all rows", etc etc etc, and of course all that once for every SQL dialect. How is this remotely useful?

Comment: @l4mpi Probably most of those exist. Why would that not be useful? If you enter a natural language question of what you are trying to do into a search engine and it brings back a page of answers and comments discussing that one particular aspect. You are also assuming some level of a priori knowledge. E.g. In SQL Server renaming a column is not part of the ALTER TABLE grammar.

Comment: @MartinSmith It's certainly not useful if it is a duplication of the official documentation. It might be useful for SO ad revenue if a SO question like the above appears before the docs in a google search, but I can't see how this is useful to the community. It just teaches people to ask things they could trivially look up on existing sources on SO instead of doing research. And call me old-fashioned, but if someone wants to mess with a database I do sincerely hope they've had the common sense to acquire at least some basic a priori knowledge about RDBMS and SQL before attempting any task.

Comment: @l4mpi Clearly more than 1,000 people found the top answer there useful. Probably many more unregistered users too. They could have looked at the official grammar for the same information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx but that also covers a lot of aspects not relevant to the matter at hand. The task oriented SO answer is much quicker to parse and get on with your day rather than wading through that. Certainly I benefited last year from reading plenty of "how do I do x in jquery?" answers on SO when I had the same question.

Comment: @BrianRoach The problem is not all people has the same level of understanding. I, for one, is somewhat new in web programming. Sometimes I ask for something trivia, but because it's so trivia, I can't find the answer to my question anywhere. I knew the answer is over there in front of my eyes, but I just can't see it sometimes. That's also the same with duplicate question. Not all people can derive the solution from other similar problem. Sometimes when my question marked as duplicate, and when people actually give answers anyway, the working answer is very different than in the duplicate.

Comment: @l4mpi, sometimes, a noob may not know a synonym for "delete", which is probably listed as "remove" in the documentation, without any searchable occurrence of "delete". Oversimplified example, but I hope you get the point. There's no such thing as perfect documentation, such that experienced humans who have been through the noob boot camp are the best resources.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that specific question has a valid close reason regarding not showing effort, although a fair point can probably made for "unclear" - What about nested brackets? What about unmatched brackets? If you're being pedantic (not sure if this applies) - how do you want them highlighted? Any specific colour? Plugin or natively?

---

In general, I see if it fits into either of the below:

- Unclear

  Okay, sure, we know that OP's just asking for the code. Just providing the code may be sufficient, but that's not going to teach OP much (and then they'll be back with a near-identical question later because they didn't understand the code), and there's that off chance that they actually want to learn.

  We should always try to explain things.

  But what should we explain? Should we explain basic language syntax? No, that'll probably be too long. But if they understood basic language syntax, wouldn't they have at least tried to write some code? Should we explain what every function does? Should we explain our thought process as to how we got to this code, since OP doesn't seem able to do this him/herself?

  Additionally, let's consider an example:

  > How do I sort an array in Java?

  Ok, sure, easy - `Arrays.sort(array)`.

  Okay, we can probably fairly easily mention the algorithm used here, and its complexity (should we?), but what about a short description of the algorithm, some pseudo-code, a visualization, etc.?

  But wait, are we even allowed to use the standard API? This is probably homework, so maybe they have to implement it themselves. If so, maybe they're supposed to use a specific sorting algorithm - we don't know. Maybe the data is of a specific type and that's supposed to be a determining factor in picking the algorithm. What are the performance requirements?

  So, unclear.
- Too broad

  For reasons very similar to the above, we could close it as too broad. These close reasons are a bit too similar for my liking. Flip a coin if you're not sure?

---

I don't actually think using either of the above reasons for these questions (where appropriate) is a particularly good idea. The lack of clarity or broadness is usually not particularly clear in this case, so either OP (and others) is left confused, or we have to leave additional clarification in the comments as to why it was / could be closed.

I suspect the questions that were *supposed* to be closed with the "minimal understanding" reason are ones that should now be closed as "unclear" / "too broad". Fair enough on removing that reason because questions that shouldn't be closed were closed (not that I agree), but now we're left with reasons that makes sense in some vague sense, but doesn't really seem to help many people understand why the question was closed, which is exactly why the reason is there.

Answer (score -3):

As I have just joined in to the site, I cannot comment hence putting my perspective as a 'noob'.

I filed this 'making git more verbose' query [Is there a way to make git more verbose while pulling from a repo.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436971/is-there-a-way-to-make-git-more-verbose-while-pulling-from-a-repo)

Now I have read a bit of git-scm book http://git-scm.com/book/en/ as well as did some initial google searches and stack overflow searches but couldn't find an answer.

Now, this question would probably be imperative in all those places where bandwidth speed is an issue OR the remote repo. is very large (think for instance, the linux kernel). In both these use-cases people might be hit with this. Some people might let git be, while others who are more hands-on are likely to worry if things are going in the right direction or not (especially if other net traffic is also there).

My main point is, it's not easy to know why a query is being asked and from which perspective and benefit of doubt should 'sometimes' be given to the questioner.

Comment: The problem is for every one of potentially good questions like yours there is 10-20 where the user did NOT bother reading anything (never mind a book) - and they all look the same. **The solution to prevent people from closing questions like yours as "How to do X" is trivial** - you should simply mention at the end "I looked in this and that resource; or I tried this and that command". ...

Comment: ... It instantly turns your question from "How do I do X" to "How do I do X? I tried Y and Z" which is 100% welcome and typically upvoted and treasured. That extra info in the end makes it very easy to know "why a query is being asked and from which perspective", as you put it.

Comment: As far as benefit of the doubt - that's a nice ideal. Sadly, 1/20 good-to-bad ration makes it an unfeasible approach in this reality.