# What to do in Low-Quality queue, when question is a "How Do I...?"

Tags: discussion, review-queues, questions, low-quality-posts

I've been trying to do more reviews recently, to help with the "low-quality" posts recently. However, I'm finding more often than not there are lots of "How Do I..." questions in there?

According to the top-post on [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for "How do I do X?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) the correct response is not to mark it for closure, but to downvote. But I can't do that from that review queue?

Is there a reason why I can't downvote it from there? Having to fire-up another tab, to find the question seems inefficient, but I hate to just leave the question there

Comment: It's debatable whether the voting buttons are necessary in the LQ review queue - frequently many of the items are so low quality that they need *action*, not *voting*. For example I just checked that queue now, and the first dozen items were all link only answers - these need to be converted to a comment or possibly outright deleted, voting them down doesn't make them any better.

Comment: I agree a lot *do* require action (and I close/edit those ones) but I'm wondering about the "How Do I ..." ones. To be honest, I hadn't noticed that the question title was a link to the original question, which slightly speeds up the downvoting, but it still disrupts the process. Obivously one argument would be that we should actually close some of these How Do I... questions, but that doesn't seem to be the current thinking.

Comment: What do you have against "How do I" questions?  They're arguably the most useful kind of question that can be asked.  Certainly they are more useful to others than the rampage of highly-localized troubleshooting questions that are the current fashion.

Comment: They tend to be "can somebody google this for me" questions.  Yes, very useful.  To the questioner.  The rampage of duplicates and copy/pasta, not so much.  Pretty hard to get rid of these days so they just keep coming, *everybody* likes to crowd-source googling.

Comment: I don't know if you see the full content of the question in the review queue but if not I would strongly advice against a direct downvote possibility.

Answer (score 20):

The review queues are designed to be specifically targeting certain actions to some very specific problems.  When using any queue you will always come across problems that that queue wasn't designed to solve, and you generally won't be given tools to solve those other problems.  If you want to open up the post in a new tab and solve those other problems, great, more power to you.  If you don't, *that's fine*.  If the post in question doesn't have whatever problems that queue is specifically designed to solve, then act accordingly.

The VLQ queue is there to close/delete posts that are so completely awful and unsalvageable that they need to be cleansed with fire.  When you see those posts, you should be voting to close/delete them.  When you see post that have other problems, say problems that warrant a downvote but not a close/delete vote, then *from the review queue* no action is needed.  If you want to optionally leave the queue and do some other action, that's your decision.