# Why "Skip" and not "I'm Done" in Low Quality Queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

The options while in the Low Quality Queue are:

- Looks Good
- Edit
- Recommend Deletion
- Skip

If I want to downvote the answer, I have to click the link, add an optional comment and then return to the Low Quality Queue. Then my option is either Looks Good or Skip. I could Recommend Deletion, but it might not qualify. I could Edit, if it is possible to recover such an answer.

But why Skip? If I could downvote the answer within the Low Quality Queue (I can already comment), the option would say "I'm Done" instead of "Skip". By using "Skip", it's like I have not taken any action at all. Clicking Looks Good is disingenuous. It doesn't look good!

Comment: 'Skip' should be used when you *don't know* if it looks good or should be deleted instead. 'Looks Good' means: I've done all I could to keep this answer from remaining in the queue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok, but what if I downvoted it and added a comment to improve. It's neither Looks Good or Skip

Comment: I agree that 'looks good' is a misleading button label, we are discussing changing it. It really means: should not be deleted, I've done my bit to improve insofar necessary.

Comment: Recent relevant comment discussion: [Should I be concerned about delete reviews on reasonable but brief answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/29453)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I could have sworn a couple years ago it was different. Something changed a long the way.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the Late Answer and First Post queues?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yep, I think so too. Now if we could model the Low Quality Queue similar to the Late Answers Queue

Comment: @staticx They are designed to do very different things however, and there are radically different things that *can be done* in each queue.  First/last posts are there because they've identified posts with probable problems and want them to be reviewed *for any possible problems that an experienced user might be able to address* in order to help out the new user.  The VLQ queue is there to burn things with fire.

Comment: Count me in the "confused by 'Looks Good'" camp. I've skipped too many questions I thought were not "good" but not just *enough bad*. I'd love to use the review algos to do more than just a delete/keep binary decision.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the low quality queue is to evaluate posts that are of such low quality that it is important for them to be nuked from orbit and completely destroyed.  It focuses on doing just that one thing, and not evaluating any number of other possible actions that might be taken on that post.

Either the post needs to be deleted, it doesn't need to be deleted, you can fix it so that after you have fixed it it doesn't need to be deleted, or you have no idea what to do.

If you don't know if this post should be deleted or not then you should click "skip".

If you know that this post should *not* be deleted (which is what you've claimed to be the case here), then you should click "looks good".  This is true even if you happen to take actions outside of the scope of the queue, such as downvoting the post.

Comment: But it doesn't look good....

Comment: @staticx Again, "looks good" means, "should not be deleted".  It doesn't mean, "this is an amazing post that I <3".

Comment: Add that the `"Looks Good"` button is mis-labeled, and that's a good answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator It is a label that happens to be confusing for some, yes, and it should probably be changed for that reason, but strictly speaking it's not mis-labeled.  It is simply commonly mis-understood.  You simply need to understand what you are evaluating posts for, and why the queue exists.  You're saying that the very specific aspects of the post being evaluated look good, rather than that every single entirely unrelated aspect of the post looks good.  It's actually more confusion about the purpose of the queue than that one button.

Comment: @Servy: If it is very misleading and/or confusing, I see that as mis-labeled (as opposed to well-labeled), even if the wider context might disambiguate it. At the least it's a bad user-interface, which should be corrected (that already seems to be on the way). Either way, you might consider adding that to your answer with the emphasis you prefer. No need to conclusively discuss that nor to decide it, just a reference to that discussion would be good.

Comment: @Deduplicator Whether or not the button should be renamed is a rather separate issue from you asking how to use the queue.  This is how you should use the queue.  There are separate questions relating to proposals for improving it.

Comment: if it "focuses on doing just that one thing" (whether to delete post or not) then either "Looks Good" should be renamed to ["Don't Delete"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers/256363#comment30686_256363) or SE team make it crystal clear that they really want deletion of anything that doesn't qualify as looking good

Comment: @gnat Again, I've voiced my support for that numerous times in the past, for that specific wording in fact.  I just consider it offtopic here.