# Failed an audit, why is this spam?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5050600

And for those who can't see the original content:

> [image]

I did get a warning that the system thinks the answer is spam, but I chose "Looks OK" because it answers the question and links to [a blog post](http://igrali.com/2012/10/31/windows-phone-8-emulator-wasnt-able-to-create-the-virtual-machine/) with additional information.

Then it turned out to be an audit and I failed it.

Comment: It looks like a clear-cut link-only answer to me

Comment: When all a user does is post links to their own blog, it is overt self-promotion -> spam. When I see a 'late answer' or 'first post' that is both a link-only answer, I *always* wonder what the user affiliation is with that link.

Comment: @JanDvorak It does answer the question, the link is for additional information.

Comment: Perhaps the user has a broader history of posting similar content, triggering spam flags on all of it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Linking to own blog is fine if you don't do it in a majority of your answers

Comment: It's a bit iffy though @Stijn. Removing the link, all you're left with is "In my case I have deleted other virtual machines". I might have held off on the spam flag if it was an isolated instance, but it doesn't provide much of an answer.

Comment: @Bart if that's all what's needed to solve the problem, what else should there be in the answer? It's straight to the point.

Comment: There are 8 steps in the blog post @Stijn ...

Comment: @JanDvorak: nope, I know that, but that's why you *check* and verify that it isn't *all a user does*.

Comment: @Bart 8 possible solutions, not 8 steps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the problem is, once they do get removed, a check of the user's profile reveals no evidence of such misconduct (unless the profile gets deleted or has no answers)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I agree that in this specific case, the situation isn't cut and dry. Automated audit picking can sometimes pick a bad example. Note that this account has no answers, so you could have detected that this is an audit because you checked the user account.

Comment: @MartijnPieters should moderators have a way to exclude posts deleted as spam from audit selection?

Comment: @JanDvorak: only after the fact, perhaps. They have their work cut out as it is with keeping junk of the site without having to check if something suitable for audits too. The problem is bigger with *First Post* and *Close* audit questions that were bad examples, and we can vote those down to take them out of consideration, posts like these are harder to remove from the pool.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but the blog doesn't seem to be the users blog. And that was very easy to check out. Just go to the blog. Same person = advertising. Different person = someone trying to help out / not spam

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu: Right, and noone ever lied on their profile. In *this* case the profile *looks* genuine enough, but how can we ever be sure about that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters if you go to the site you can see another SE account (of the blogs owner). I'm not saying that many posts aren't spam. And I'm not saying that anyone should start reading any blog top to bottom just to make absolutely sure that it's spam. But a quick look at the page linked and of the profile of the poster takes under a minute, and can help out a bunch to make up your mind if it's spam or not. I'm just saying don't Robo-fail every answer.

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu: Of course not, and I already stated this case is not cut and dry, not enough for an audit. We certainly cannot see what *else* this specific account posted that has since been deleted. If the user did nothing but post blog links as answers all over the place, that could easily have led to all those answers being deleted as spam. Context is missing here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an unsolicited advertisement." taken from [Usage guide for spam and offensive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work/58035#58035) Regardless of the context, the answer provided a solution and a link to further explanations / solutions (therefor not spam)

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu: [Overt self promotion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) is also seen as spam. Spammers can be very subtle and devious; I've recently flagged a post that *looked* like an answer but linked a keyword to a company website.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But my point was that it was not self promotion. But just to make sure I didn't screw something up, is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24179677/1826335) spam? Just want to know if I should leave it up or not. (i was really just trying to help, and I hope I don't come off as rude or anything)

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu: You explicitly disclosed you are not affiliated, the link is relevant, it is an integral part of your answer, that is definitely not spam.

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu: I *don't know* if it was self promotion here, as we have too little context. I'm more saying that I am very suspicious and jaded; spammers have used every trick in the book, plus invented some more, to avoid detection. Without further context, this doesn't look like spam to me, no, which is why it is a bad audit post.

Answer (score 15):

So that's an interesting case. It was flagged as both "not an answer" and spam by different users. It was flagged at a time when there weren't many moderators active on the site, so one of us didn't act on the spam flag.

Instead, it was automatically deleted from review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4952811 after receiving enough delete votes (for being a link-based answer). That deletion immediately validated both the "not an answer" and spam flags.

I would have declined or dismissed the spam flag on that, because this doesn't fit the pattern of traditional spam. It's a user posting a link to an older tutorial, and not an obvious attempt to spam a blog or product. I don't see abusive behavior here.

That said, this still would have become an audit case because of the validated "not an answer" flag on it. [We've been instructed to remove "see this tutorial" answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) when flagged, and validate the flags on them. While I don't necessarily agree that all such answers should be deleted, the community has spoken and decided these answers are not appropriate here.

I'm a little concerned about audit cases being identified from automatically validated flags in the Low Quality Posts review queue, particularly spam and offensive flags. Perhaps the system should leave those to be acted on by moderators when a post is deleted by a community vote like this. Maybe validation of flags by non-moderator actions shouldn't cause something to be used as an audit case. I don't have the stats to see if this is a real problem, but [moderators were instructed to be strict with these flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently), and the community doesn't have that kind of guidance.

Comment: I think it's not an interesting case at all, but plain mistake in the algorithm that picks "known bad" audits which apparently should ignore any answer that isn't "verified" by 20K / diamond delete vote. Deletion by review is hardly a reliable indication, given that most of (30,000) reviewers in the VLQ queue [aren't really expected to have level of understanding sufficient to produce audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256364/839601)

Comment: @gnat - Thus the last paragraph. The way that audits are assigned was built at a time when only moderators handled these flags. Now that normal community members are, does this cause a problem? Given that this isn't the first case I've seen of this, maybe, but a dev might be able to show that this is a rare case.

Comment: Having found your answer, I won't post a new question about it, but please do something about it. Here's [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5093826).

Comment: @LevLevitsky - Yeah, that was spam-flagged and it was accepted when the user themselves deleted their answer. That should not have been approved, since it was a malicious flag from another user to attack that answer. I've cleared the spam flag so this won't be used as an audit again. Sorry about the bad audit, and thanks for pointing this out.