# What to do about incorrectly failed review audits?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this late answer review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5054836), but I'm sure the audit system was wrong here.

Is there a mechanism to flag or challenge these incorrect audits, besides bringing it up on Meta?

Comment: [I wish there was.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/135615)

Comment: That said, this is bizarre. Why is that an audit? It was never flagged as spam, a non-answer, or very low quality, and was disputed in review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4895921 . Frankly, I don't think it should have been deleted, [but that's a separate discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers). I don't see how this would qualify as an audit.

Comment: @BradLarson It was deleted by three 20k rep users, not through a review system or by a mod, so the deletion seems fine to me, but you are correct that it shouldn't qualify as an audit.

Comment: I'm sure that something must be done with the audit system. Take a look at [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260752/3315914)