# Bad first question audit experience: incorrect audit, audit doesn't help reviewer, and unactionable after

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit, first-questions

I don't often review things, but decided to try out the first questions queue for fun. I got [an audit which was bad for a few reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31608913):

- I believe the audit was just incorrect altogether. The question is a bit lacking in detail (the version of `black` being used, the way linting is being run, etc.) and somewhat poorly formatted. I chose 'Share feedback' to leave a friendly comment asking for more details, which seems appropriate to me, but this causes the audit to be failed.
- After failing the audit, it doesn't provide any details on what *should* have happened. It just says 'STOP! Look and Listen.', then tells you you weren't paying attention. It frankly comes off as a bit insulting given that there's not any actual guidance.

[image: audit-feedback]

- Finally, after having a bad audit, there's no clear way to dispute it or report it. After searching MSO, I saw a comment which said to make a post here with the `disputed-review-audits` tag, which is fine, but a bit cumbersome. It's surprising to me there's no clear way in the UI to flag when an audit seems incorrect or any instructions given on what to do.

Apologies if these things have been discussed before. I just found it all to be a surprisingly poor user experience, so I wanted to share feedback in case it can help lead to improvements in the future for others!

Comment: Certainly room for improvement on that specific question. It's also apparently [quite a popular audit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71673404/timeline) choice by the system and one which has impacted a few other users who opted to Share Feedback ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31607043), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31584516), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31538732)).

Comment: There is a related FR for that second part of having a clearer way to dispute or report the audit: [Audit Review Flag or Challenge button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415069/15497888)

Comment: This wasn't a great audit, that's for sure. I've now taken steps to remove it from the audit pool in the future.

Comment: Apparently, the user has [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912264/python-3-9-8-fails-using-black-and-importing-typed-ast-ast3) [such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71673404/importerror-cannot-import-name-unicodefun-from-click) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71673404/importerror-cannot-import-name-unicodefun-from-click). A friendly comment clarifying that information is needed for the questions to be/remain useful seems to be exactly the right action.

Comment: Yet another instance of [Why did I fail this first question review audit after choosing sharing feedback?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412271/6083675). Hopefully the system can be changed so you don't fail when writing your own comment this way on a post.

Comment: Previously asked and [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment/262511#262511). Hope they get this fixed... again.