# The ambiguous reviewing tasks of low quality posts

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing an answer and was quite sure that it was a review audit generated by the system because it had 6 upvotes; however the answer was only one short paragraph and hence I considered it as a low quality post, as I thought it required a broader explanation.

Hence, I recommended it for deletion. Then what happened next was:

[image: *STOP! Look and Listen* audit failure]

I suspect that this answer was upvoted because the answerer is famous author of some good java books, but the answer still is of low quality and needs to be explained further.

Comment: VLQ would mean it should be deleted, but just why? It's an answer, I can't judge the quality but in any case it's a valid answer.

Comment: It is a decent answer.  If you don't understand it then you should ask a question about it instead of trying to destroy it.  And use the Skip button more often.

Comment: I know the answer is correct,but it needed to be explained.... @HansPassant ...these type of oneliners can easily be found by googling, or on other forums but ' **explaination** ' is why we come here at stackoverflow may be

Comment: That's  what's voting for ...

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was concerned about here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers . Just because an answer is short does not mean it is worth deleting.

Answer (score 17):

There was absolutely *no need* to vote to delete a post like this.

Outside the review queue, if you find a post that you feel isn't helpful *enough*, then you'd either not vote, or you'd down vote, but not delete it. In the Low Quality review queue, you'd perhaps leave a comment asking for such a post to be improved by the author. Deletion here would actively rob the site of content that was OK enough.

Vote to delete posts that are either [not answers at all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer), or cannot be salvaged in any way. Go and edit a post if you feel you can fix the quality issues.

The LQ queue is our janitorial *there is a spill on isle three* queue; if it is not an actual spill, just straighten the produce on the shelf and move on to something else.