# Does it matter that short answers are often mistaken for comments?

Tags: discussion

When reviewing Low Quality Posts, I often see short answers that have been voted for deletion with the "This does not provide an answer to the question" comment selected. Sometimes they really aren't answers, but often they actually do make an attempt to answer the question, and I assume they are mistaken for comments simply because they are short.

Usually these answers, in addition to being short, are not particularly useful, but sometimes they are only short because someone has asked a question with a very simple answer. Granted, the value of questions that can be answered so simply is debatable, but this does not change the fact that their answers really are not comments.

Does it matter that people are voting to delete a certain category of answers for the wrong reason if most of the answers in this category seem to have little to no value? If so, is there anything that can be done to motivate people to apply "not an answer" flags and "this is a comment" delete votes more judiciously when they encounter short answers?

Comment: Leave a counter comment.  Or edit the short answer to make it more obvious it's an answer.  A lot of times, legitimate (but short) answers are ordered in a strange way that makes them look like clarification comments instead of answers.

Comment: Related: ["Should I be concerned about delete reviews on reasonable but brief answers?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers)

Comment: I really love your point, thanks for writing this.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with being succinct if you are adequately answering the question while keeping in mind that any implied meaning must allow for the user's ability to infer the same. [Veni, vidi, vici](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni,_vidi,_vici) still stands as one of the best examples of stating no more than was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it matters. The fact that other similar answers should be deleted shouldn't affect an answer.

Each answer should be judged on it's own merits and flaws.

The fact that it is short doesn't necessarily make it a low quality answer, however this doesn't even matter as bad answers are still answers and should not be deleted, they should be downvoted, edited or commented on.

If the answer, answers the question then it is ok and should not be deleted.