# How to handle questions which should be closed but get bountied?

Tags: discussion, bounty

https://stackoverflow.com/q/24077473/1048539

This question is basically asking, "write this code for me" and apparently was not closed before the user was eligible to add a bounty.

Because it has a bounty no one can cast close votes.

I have downvoted the question since it is basically off-topic for Stack Overflow and at best belongs on Code Review.

- Is there something else I should do when coming across a question like this, with a bounty?

---

Note that this discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253069/1048539) indicates questions like the above are not necessarily worth closing (I personally disagree very strongly but have stopped VTC'ing questions like that). The linked question clearly is not closeable according to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253096/1048539).

Because of this, I do not believe my question here is a duplicate of the linked question, which refers specifically to questions which are "officially closable."

It just feels wrong to allow someone to basically bounty for "give me teh codez."

Comment: I can't believe this, check this out, [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22698257/1542290), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23611138/1542290), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960049/) <-- All these are like rep for work type questions..

Comment: @unit3524344 technically, according to some discussion on meta (which I disagree with), questions which are "give me teh codez" are not off topic unless they are too broad/etc. In some cases you can have a specific, defined, clear problem and have it be "give me teh codez" and not have any relevant close reason.

Answer (score 3):

Moderators can cancel a bounty and, in such a case, can close in one fell swoop.

So, you can flag the post and use the "Other" option to explain the situation. Don't skimp on details; make sure you're clear as to what you think should happen and why.