# How to correctly flag bad questions?

Tags: discussion, flags

sometimes when I flag questions that are:

"here is what I want" type as low quality

but the question is tagged as [on hold] for too broad instead

Is there a FAQ for how to flag with the correct Flag?

Comment: If the question is already on hold, it probably doesn't need flagging

Comment: Basically the entirety of the help center, and FAQs on meta, make up the answer to this question.

Comment: @OGHaza His point is he flags a post as VLQ, and later finds it closed as "too broad" when checking up on it and doesn't understand why.

Comment: @Servy, ah, right you are.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you flag something, all you're saying is "there's a problem here - I've done my best to describe it, please handle it appropriately."

It is up to whoever handles the flag to decide what the appropriate action is.

In the case of close flags, 5 people must agree...

1. ...that there is a problem with the post that requires closure
2. ...on an appropriate description for that problem

You're providing them with a *hint* in your flag, but they're free to ignore it; chances are, they've probably seen a lot more bad questions than you have and the system trusts them to decide on the appropriate course of action.

For more information on flagging, along with links to usage guides, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: Please also mention spam and offensive flags.

Comment: There's a wealth of information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts); no reason to reiterate it all.