# How to close "Please write code" type questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507158/how-to-make-virustotal-uploader-using-api-c-sharp), we see these from time to time. They're effectively "Can you write some code for me?" or "Please write demo code" questions.

Firstly should these be closed? If so what is the appropriate way to close these?

Comment: related: [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for “How do I do X?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253069/247702) and [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/247702) (perhaps one of these is a dupe)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Either flag/close them as:

- unclear what you're asking (because it's unclear where you're stuck at, unclear what you've tried ...)
- too broad

Comment: there's also "debugging questions need code in the question [and you surely have some code, don't you?]"

Comment: Well, I flagged some of these questions as 'Unclear what you are asking' or 'Debugging questions ...' and most of them got disputed, about half of the questions got deleted later on, even though the flag was disputed