# Specific warnings to newbies about homework/code-writing, please debug and SSCCE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

After a fair bit of reviewing I am finding a consistent high proportion of newbie questions in these categories. Is it possible that more help up front would help stem the tide?

First: "please write my code for me". See also: [How to close "Please write code" type questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262103/how-to-close-please-write-code-type-questions). Personally I think this comes up often enough that a specific close reason would be justified, which I work around by writing a comment to this effect. This is a **big** category, and really deserves some specific newbie advice.

Second: "please debug my code" questions have been raised many times here, and I won't rehash the debate. I'm just asking for more specific advice targeted at newbies to try to stem the flow of horrible code with trivial bugs.

Third: "please find a bug that is not in the code I've shown you". It's all very well producing a page of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) help after the event, but I've spent significant time looking for things that just aren't there, and eventually voted to close in frustration.

So the question is: can we conceivably provide some specific, blunt advice specifically to newbies before they ask someone to write their code or find their trivial or invisible bugs?

The alternative is simply close early and close often, in the hope that next time they'll try harder.

---

When and where? At the point where a new user asks their first question. Possibly anyone who asks a question with a rep of less than 10 or 20. Simple, straightforward, blunt.

- Stack Overflow is not here to do you your assignments or homework for you. Don't ask.
- Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please do not ask us to write your code for you.
- Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. Please do not ask us to find simple bugs and mistakes in your programs. You should be able to find them yourself using a debugger or similar tools.
- Stack Overflow can help with tough problems but only after you've narrowed it down to the minimum code, and then posted the complete problem. See SSCCE.

Remember that Stack Overflow is about good questions as well as good answers. Don't abuse it.

Comment: I try to leave a comment citing related, complete, working examples.

Comment: How do we target these warnings? Are you suggesting an analysis of the text of the question before posting? This kind of information is just noise to someone who's not asking about for either of these things.

Comment: @JoshCaswell:  See edit

Comment: Are you familiar with [the click-through page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that new users go through when asking? A lot of overlap with your bullets.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Familiar would overstate the position. I have seen it, but not recently. This is exactly the kind of place I had in mind. It definitely needs updating (follow the homework link).

Comment: Incidentally, it's [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), not 'SCCEE.' (Edited the question to reflect that, hope you don't mind - and that I didn't misunderstand an unknown acronym). Also, we now have Stack Overflow's very own take on SSCCE: '[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/).’

Comment: How do you determine what a reasonable level of competence is for 'debugging' ? There are a lot of basic concepts related to programming that people like me just don't understand. Our questions would be 'simple bugs and mistakes' to a competent programmer. But I bet that competent programmer makes 'simple mistakes' from the perspective of a genius.
This is why we vote isn't it? The community itself will decide what it thinks is appropriate.

Comment: @bsafh: Nice to get some input from someone not long out of newbie-land, but we really aren't talking about relative skills here. Go read 50 questions asked by rep 1 users and you should see what I mean. SO is simply not a place providing beginner debug tutorials, and we need to say so.

Comment: Some / Most of these "newbie" questions are better served when asked in [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) as they ask for quick references and simple reviews that includes a bug to be found. It's a shame that there is an entry reputation limit for [using the chat room as a privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat).

Comment: @trashgod Half the questions I come across in the first post queue have no obvious sign of working so I typically downvote it and add a comment asking them what they've tried. Only to check back 5 minutes later to see that a couple of high rep users will have already answered it with a short code snippet and (sometimes) a very brief explanation. It's pretty disheartening. The SQL and regex tags are probably the worst for it.

Comment: When I asked my first question on so it took three days of over-my-head research to make what seemed to be a "good" question, which surely is a duplicate; I honestly couldn't understand the C++ refs. Not everyone cares so much about rules. How do you make sure your preemptive suggestions get through to the newb? Also, what happens when they ask a first question, supposedly by your standard, and that is quickly forgotten by the time the next "bad" question is asked two hours before their assignment is due?

Comment: @Unihedron Big fat NO. "Write my code for me", "find my bug for me", etc, belong nowhere. They're inherently bad, not merely misplaced.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: they do belong somewhere; in the hands of a paid technician. Show "me" the money!

Comment: @DavidThomas: Thanks. It was a typo (I think). And I can never find MCVE when I need it.

Comment: 40+ yrs as a pro in IBM systems, but fairly new and low-rep in SO. I came here because of declining question quality on some competing sites (where, e.g., I was on the Advisory Board). It seems to be accelerating everywhere. I hoped SO would be (or remain) as an exception, but I've seen it here in my short time. It's already on my nerves. It's market driven and apparently beyond control by high-quality (not _necessarily_ "high rep") members.

Comment: @user2338816: There are good questions here, and on Programmers, and good answers. Oldies make major contributions here (not just on ancient (computer) history) but the the flow of newbie dross is a real problem.

Comment: +1 I was about to post similarly on the "please write my code" reason (having just closed [yet another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888236) ). Perhaps the message could be "This appears to be off-topic because stackoverflow is not a coding service" or "...because we will not do your job for you"

Comment: Can we add something about Java code that attempts to use `==` to compare strings?

Comment: I was going to post an answer to this but I went off on a tangent and it turned in to a feature request of its own: [The Good, The Bad & The Ugly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly)

Comment: @Tanner: That was quite some tangent!

Comment: @david.pfx When I was trying to get to 50 rep I looked for questions that I might be able to accurately answer, or edits that would improve a post. As you can imagine with my being not-a-programmer it meant spending a lot of time trawling through various queues and tags. So I've seen some of what you're referring to. It is certainly annoying when the asker has not even put in 5 mins of effort. But sometimes people like me just need something described differently for it to click. Thats where humans > doco. Chat is blocked at work, so I can understand why they post to SO.

Comment: @david.pfx indeed, I got a few paragraphs in and realised I was no longer answering you question. It did however stem from the thought that new users need a better education about how the system works.

Answer (score 51):

The actual problem seems to be that people desperate to find a solution to their homework-due-tomorrow problem won't read anything, regardless of how clear and blunt it is. Even if they read it, they are still desperate enough to try anyway - there is always a chance that someone will answer before the question is closed.

Because of this I don't believe that any UI rearrangements, even with neons and big red all-caps flashing notices will help. Other solutions have been proposed (my favourite: [Probationary period for Questions to be Answered to encourage better questions with more effective Moderation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w)), but IIRC they all have been declined/ignored.

Comment: I like your idea. We could utilize first posts queue for that. I've added it in my answer.

Comment: But if you really want to get through to someone, you need arrows and [Chiller](http://www.identifont.com/samples/itc/Chiller.gif)

Comment: But my homework is due tomorrow!!

Answer (score 17):

It's worth reflecting on the shift from programmers as a rare breed of wizards, to the new wave of kids who learn it in school, and on Khan Academy or whatever.

Inevitably, and before long, the majority of people who can code will not be programmers.

This is not really an SO issue, but SO does need a answer for it, so this discussion's important still.

Can we not just direct them to OpenStudy or something like that? Or just create a StackExchange site called StudyGroup. If people want to answer those questions (and many seem to), give them a site of their own.

Comment: This is not new, not a new wave, not a new shift. As someone who has been a paid professional programmer for almost 30 years, I have seen this kind of not-actually-competent programmer asking do-my-work-for-me questions ever since there was any kind of online forum (BBS, IRC) on which to ask. Then I rant to the nearest person about having to compete with these folks for a job.

Comment: @StephenP How has the quality changed? I look at code from the 80s and its a hell of a lot harder to do some ordinary useful things. I would think that a lazy/stupid programmer in 80s would surely be better than the same in the 2000s. Some of the libraries that come with Python or Powershell (Im on network/system side of things so thats what I know) do most of the work for us (newbies).

Comment: Ah... the days of old... Lets look back to [comp.lang.c](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/D7GWCtJjY5U) from October '93.  Not that that one is unique [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/rVmI6jHruGs) [are](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/rK-mxWiAv2A) [lots](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/PGJ51uxbtrw) [more](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/y9o9ORb4ofY)  - [some read just like SO comments](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/ezeSRGy-HE8).

Answer (score 7):

I really support what this post is driving at. As I see it, this site is about sharing knowledge. Questions that are raised are useful because it is likely that other people might encounter the same issues and therefore the question may occur to may people and the answer may be useful to many.

The reputation system is designed to reward questions and answers that are useful in that way.

A question that says "Please do my homework" or "please find my particular error in my particular code" does not share any knowledge, it just asks someone for help doing a particular piece of work. There is nothing much wrong with that - it is nice to be helpful - but I don't believe that it is quite the same thing as creating a piece of knowledge that is potentially of benefit to all, and therefore is not fitting with the objectives of this site (as I see them).

Not only that, but it discourages students or programmers from learning from learning how to code themselves, or learning how to debug.

The problem is that there is little cost for the person asking the question and some reward for anyone answering it - potentially 25 rep points. So even with those  questions that are useless to anyone but the asker, the environment still encourages both the question asker and the responder.

My proposal would be to have a solution where there is no reputation to be gained (on the Stackoverflow site) by asking or responding to these questions, while leaving it possible for someone to ask and receive help if they want it, and I think there are a number of options for this:

1. Close as duplicate (or some new status). Create a standard "How to debug a Java application with error type XXXX" answer and close any requests to this category of error. However, I am not sure this stops reputation gains and it probably does help with homework requests.
2. Move to another site. We could create a "My code doesn't work" site or a "Coding assignment" site and simply move everything off this. The risk here is that genuinely useful problems might get moved off (though I guess they could be moved back). People could frequent these other sites if they wanted, and if they want to build rep by answering homework questions, that is up to them. Note that the code review site exists, but I don't see that this site is appropriate for these problems either.

I realise this @Carl Smith has suggested a "Study Group" site (upvote), so I am kind of expanding on that idea. Maybe two sites are required though - one for debugging and one for assignment help (or maybe not).