# Is it appropriate to ask for someone to do your work for you

Tags: discussion

So the topic I'm worried about is :
If someone posts a question on how to do something but they want you to modify their code and send it back to them.
IE: they learn nothing from it .

Especially if the topic isn't particularly new as it covers many topics.
Would like to hear stack overflow's opinions before I post the example question.

Especially if this is for someone's job. There might be future complications. 
example what if the code provided isn't 100% fool proof and it breaks something as the knowledge of the OP's systems is little to none or assummed.

I think My topic might be a duplicate of 
[Specific warnings to newbies about homework/code-writing, please debug and SSCCE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266270/specific-warnings-to-newbies-about-homework-code-writing-please-debug-and-sscce)

**EDIT**
Thanks that is what I thought.
A SO User was commenting on my answer with pasteBin links to his code to change it.

here is the question.
[Using JS to keep a rollover image open until mouse leaves maps outer container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298043/using-js-to-keep-a-rollover-image-open-until-mouse-leaves-maps-outer-container/30298265)

Comment: Here is an opinion: Kill those questions. With fire. Requiring answerers to "post working code" so it can be copy-pasted right into the questioner's project/assignment must not be tolerated, lest we end up as glorified human web services.

Comment: This looks like a good example of the [Help Vampire Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to ask for someone to do your work for you

Of course not unless they are getting paid to do so. And, in that case, they need to take it somewhere else because that's not what SO is for. We help answer specific, code related questions.

> If someone posts a question on how to do something but they want you to modify their code and send it back to them.

If it is a small snippet they are stuck on then that's exactly what happens and should include an explanation as to what the problem was and how to fix it. If the person is just looking for someone to write the code and not wanting an explanation then no.

> Especially if the topic isn't particularly new as it covers many topics

New or not isn't really an issue (unless it's obsolete, not going to help anyone else, and/or is a duplicate that can already be easily found). But the second part of this statement would seem to make it too broad and should be handled accordingly (possibly down/close votes and deletion).

> A SO User was commenting on my answer with pasteBin links to his code to change it.

If you want to continue to help through pastebin or whatever, than that is entirely up to you but it shouldn't extend in the SO post past the scope of the original question. If you don't want to help further, that is also your right/decision.

Answer (score -8):

This is acceptable, but not as useful as a well-explained answer. I only upvote code-only answers if there are no better alternative answers.

Comment: *" if there are no better alternative answers."* ummm...you shouldn't vote based on *other* answers or the lack thereof. You should vote based on the merit of *that* post

Comment: There are better answers here than yours, so I feel obliged to vote this one down. (Well– let's not, as there are already a few.)