# Where to point users who ask "I want to do X. How do I do it?"

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

StackOverflow Meta!

From my short time [so far] answering questions in the computer vision / openCV section of StackOverflow, I have picked up that "How to do X?" questions, with no code shown and a lot of code required, don't fare well and usually get downvoted. This makes sense, and this is also [standard StackOverflow practice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x).

However, in image processing and computer vision, the "toolbox" programmers have is large, confusing, and usually counterintuitive, especially to beginners. To abuse the colloquialism, the computer vision toolbox is five different hammers, and most of your work is trying to turn your problem into a nail.

Many computer vision and image processing questions fall into this "How do I X?" format, because there isn't a clear, premade set of steps to find an answer and there can be a wide range of accuracies in each approach. I understand the questions behind the questions and I am happy to answer these kinds of questions, if there is a place to answer them.

**Are these "How do I X?" questions within the scope of StackOverflow?** (I assume they are not, but I think it's worth asking.) If they are not, **what is the appropriate longform answer?** (i.e, not just an anonymous downvote, but a comment or an answer.) Should they be pointed to a tutorial? A LMGTFY? Is it acceptable to answer their initial question?

Comment: Related: [Where to start](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) on programmers

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My rule of thumb here is it depends on a few things.

- Does the question show the user tried to figure it out already.  For example:

  > I've been trying to figure out how to whamboozle a gizmo, but when I try to argle the billbob, it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

  That's not bad. The user made some effort but doesn't know how to do it.
- Does the question ask a relatively small, concrete step?  Or are they asking you to do the whole project.

  IE, if someone's asking a question that has a single, short answer, that's fine.  If they're asking for something that will end up taking twenty minutes to answer, it's probably not fine.
- Is the question something that is in the basic section of the manual, that even a beginner should already know?  If not, then it's fine.  If so, then probably they should at least read page one of the manual.

  The idea here: Basic questions are okay, as long as they're not something so basic that only someone who hasn't bothered to even begin learning might ask.

  > How do I tell my c program to only do something if a variable has a certain value?
  >
  > How do I write a regular expression to find the letter C?

  Those questions aren't good, even if they were written better: they're asking something that you only ask if you haven't actually bothered to try to learn the language at all.  I include in that questions that are more complex, but ultimately show that the user simply hasn't learned *anything* about the language.  You're not expected to be an *expert*, but you are expected to have spent a day or two learning the language before you post questions here - or go read a manual or something.

  Conversely, though, if it is in the manual but is not something a beginner should know, then I'm okay with the question.  Manuals are hard to use sometimes, and searching though them might require additional understanding.

  > Is there a function that does ...

  That's perfectly reasonable, in my book, because it is easy to ask, and while it might be obvious to some, it might not be all that easy to find for a beginner.

If it passes those three rules, then I think it's okay to answer, even if it's more of a "How do I..." question.

Comment: whamboozle a gizmo :D

Comment: @Emma gizmo is deprecated since 2005.

Comment: > "when I try to argle the billbob, it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to." I would add, assuming they didn't literally just say "it doesn't work the way I want it to", but specified what they wanted it to do and what it was doing instead.

Comment: I totally want to figure out how to whamboozle a gizmo now.

Comment: The majority of my answers take me *at least* an hour to write; sometimes they involve many hours of work spread across multiple days. Suggesting that a question that takes 20 minutes to answer is too broad seems way off base, not least because time taken to write the answer needn't correspond to how much content the answer contains; it's just not a useful metric at all.

Comment: Also, asking "is there a function that does X?" instead of "how do I do X?" is definitely not an improvement, and may be harmful; if there's not a *function* that does X, per se, but there's a simple way of doing it, then you and any future readers probably just want to know *how to do X*. Framing the question in a way that makes such answers seem technically wrong isn't useful, and I can't see any reason to do it other than to avoid the "How do I do X?" format that many, like you, bizarrely hold to a higher standard.

Comment: Finally, requiring askers to exhibit failed attempts in order to make their "how-to" questions on-topic is a terrible, harmful thing to do. The result is always that you get two-questions-in-one; a debugging question, and a how-to question. This is strictly worse for somebody searching for the answer to the how-to question; they have to sift through the answers explaining how to fix the OP's broken code in order to find the answer to the how-to question that they're actually there for.

Answer (score 7):

Being a "How do I do X" question is *absolutely not* a sign that the question is off-topic. Indeed, many of our most valuable questions are of precisely that form. If you look down the list of our [highest voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) you'll see the following answers on the very first page:

- Edit an incorrect commit message in Git
- How to undo the last commit?
- Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely
- How can I make a redirect page using jQuery?
- Checking if an element is hidden
- Undo 'git add' before commit

All of these are "how do I do X" questions, and all of them are on-topic (although the jQuery one kind of sucks).

A "How do I do X" question might be worthy of closure for being too broad, or unclear. But it's never off topic just *because* it's asking how to do something. That would be silly.

Finally, an important note. It's also unnecessary for the user to make a gratuitous display of "effort" in the form of dumping the code of their broken and illogical attempt at solving the problem into the question. Effort is expected insofar as the asker is required to search for duplicates before posting and ask their question clearly and unambiguously. It's also desirable (though not a matter to be enforced through the closure system) for them to ask their question as succinctly as possible and in perfect English. It *may* be useful (or even vital) for them to include code that doesn't work if there's a seemingly obvious way of doing X which actually fails, but that's an edge case; most "How do I do X?" questions do not in any way benefit from exhibiting broken code.

Comment: I agree with you in general, but the problem is that many users won't: unfortunately, for every "*How do I do X?*" question, there will always be people keen to downvote or close as too broad/insufficient research, whether they have any knowledge of the topic or not...