# How would you handle a question that doesn't demonstrate minimal efforts?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

#### Clarification: I'm not asking for alternative close vote.

Look at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327880/removing-all-strings-from-a-list-containing-a-mix-of-strings-and-numbers):

---

> I have a list which contains a mix of strings and numbers eg
>
> `old_list = [23, 35, string, 42, string]`
>   I would like list to look like this
>
> `new_list = [23,35,45]`
>
> Is there a simple way to do this?

---

On similar questions, I usually comment something like:

> Please don't provide ready solutions for such questions. We *don't* want to encourage them here. Let's help OP by letting him try first by himself.

I really understand the intention of users to help, but I think that by providing ready to copy-and-paste solutions (even with explanation) is likely to achieve the opposite - encouraging users to ask bad questions and make them rely on others to provide a solution for them.

I'm really not sure how to handle this kind of posts; First I thought that since we no longer have the "lack of research efforts" CV, and the question has many possible solutions, I would go with the "too broad" option, but [some users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327880/removing-all-strings-from-a-list-containing-a-mix-of-strings-and-numbers?noredirect=1#comment60278873_36327880) don't always agree.

What makes it harder on me is the fact that sometimes moderators give answers for such questions, and now I'm really not sure if I'm doing the right thing by voting to close questions asking "how to" without demonstrating minimal understanding or research efforts.

I would like to know how more experienced users would handle such questions.

---

Here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330705/map-with-list-of-values-to-list-in-java-8) example. Should it really be answered with a copy-paste answer? This **will not** be helping OP to learn by himself!

Comment: It does not matter what other users think about the way you vote.  It is your vote and you have the right to cast it any way you want.  Do not explain why you voted the way you did, that just generates noise.  If you want SO to be the place where programmers find solutions for non-trivial problems then that is your prerogative as well.

Comment: Isn't this actually a camouflaged "Is there **any** way to do this?" question? I.e., just another  "send me ur codez" ...

Comment: Related [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for “How do I do X?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x), and several [others on the `codez` topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=codez)

Comment: That's not really a duplicate, I'm not asking to add another close reason. I was just expecting from more experienced users not to answer poor questions, and that made me think that I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: I think the "simple" is redundant. I guess everyone would prefer a simple solution over a complicated one if there is a solution at all. So it is kind of auto-attached to every question already.

Comment: "I was just expecting from more experienced users not to answer poor questions." But what does it mean? What should be done if someone doesn't meet these expectations? You ask about encouragement/discouragement.

Comment: @Trilarion Maybe the title is confusing.

Comment: I read 'simple' as 'most obvious solution that is sure to work'.   A more flexible design, one that is, say,  more easily debugged, uses state-machine instead of direct code, uses more functions instead of a monolithic main() are useless to the OP because its prof/OP will know that the homework assignment was outsourced.  I downvote/closevote all such questions immediate.

Comment: That's **NOT** a duplicate.. Did you guys read my question?....

Comment: 'simple' is in the same set as 'consider', 'explain' and 'in detail' - 'do all of my assignment so I do not need to do any work' touchstones.

Comment: @MartinJames that's true. But I'm not asking to add another close-vote, which is the duplicated question.. for some reason.

Comment: we use to have a "too localized" close reason for precisely this case, where doing anything but giving the OP copy/paste code wouldn't truly answer the question

Answer (score 2):

The reason we want effort and research, is because it brings multiple desirable qualities to the question

1. One thing that effort does for you, is it lets you find existing answers, so you don't have to ask your own, so Check wither the question is a duplicate.  If it is a duplicate, **close it as a duplicate**
2. Another thing that effort does, is it helps you understand your problem better yourself, so that you can explain it in a comprehensible way to us. If the OP's question doesn't make much sense, **close it as unclear what you're asking**.
3. Another thing that effort does, is it solves what parts of the problem you can solve, and it helps you identify precisely where your problem is.   If a question is asking you to do provide multiple answers, or if it is asking for an answer that is too big, then **close it as too broad**
4. Finally, if you can't find any specific problem with the question other than a vague sense that the OP hasn't earned it, then go ahead and **downvote** the question.
5. If you're feeling charitable, but don't want to write code for the op, explain at a **high level** how you would solve their problem.  Odds are, if you made it this far, that their question has multiple steps, since if it only had one step, then it shouldn't fall under the "too broad" category.  Tell the OP what the steps are, and you don't have to tell them how to do those steps, especially if they're fundamental things that every programmer should know.  it is **Important** to do this in good faith.  I.E. Don't make a post like this to be condescending to the OP.  Do it because identifying the high-level solution is an important step.

Comment: The question is what to do with questions that don't demonstrate a minimal level of effort, not why providing a minimal level of effort is important.

Comment: @Servy and my answer is about what you should do with a question that you feel hasn't demonstrated enough effort.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm really not sure if I'm doing the right thing by voting to close
>   questions asking "how to" without demonstrating minimal understanding
>   or research efforts.

Here's the thing: you and the mod are both right.

The mod is right that lack of research/understanding, *in and of itself*, is not a close reason so you should not be trying to close a question if that's all that's wrong with it. Not every bad question is closeable.

You are right in that most of these questions need closing because there's *almost always something else wrong* with questions like these. It is often true that these questions have too many possible answers or that a correct answer would be too long (because the OP expects an entire program to be written for them from scratch).

In this instance you and a mod happened to disagree over whether a problem had too many possible answers. Disagreements happen. If you're using the close reasons on questions where you think they legitimately apply and you don't consistently find yourself on the wrong side of the community consensus, then you're fine.