# Where is the line for deciding if "give me teh codez" questions should be closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, review-audits

There is a lot of contrary precedence and advice regarding those questions known as "give me teh codez" [or GMTCs]. The consensus is clearly to downvote, but what of close votes? **Given two "How do I X? Plz thnx" questions, what makes one close-voteable and the other not?**

**Stance 1:** Following the site precedents and the majority of review audits seems to suggest that most GMTCs should be closed as "too broad".

**Stance 2:** Major answers on SOMeta (including [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253096/472647)) claim that *some* GMTCs should be closed as "too broad", and others shouldn't - that the fact that it is a GMTC is not a good enough reason to close.

In the linked answer above, three questions are given which are *apparently* considered "good questions", but for some reason, I cannot see the distinction between them and the bad examples given in the same answer. The only visible difference is that the "good examples" are highly upvoted, and are *very old* protected community questions (apparently OPd by Jeff Atwood)? Since we judge questions on merit, not poster, what makes these different? I really want to know - I just cannot see it.

The help documents seem to suggest that questions should have specific, verifiable problems, not just be vampirically asking for code. Yet, the close reason 'too broad' is applied without any consistency. High rep users (and many audits) close "give me teh codez" questions as "too broad" on a regular basis, and this is treated as correct, until it isn't.

**We need some consistency.** What makes an unabashed demand for finished code acceptable in one case, and unacceptable in another? **Our site has no established standard for this,** as the examples in both directions are indistinguishable. If our standard really is to leave GMTC questions open, why is the entire site precedence wholly contrary?

I am irritated by this because I hate inconsistency. I can adapt to leaving GMTC questions open and downvoting them in principle. However, the current precedent sets the entirety of our review audit system, so following that "don't close" guideline will undoubtedly lead to a review ban. I encounter no less than two audits a day that follow the precedent of closing GMTCs as "too broad".

The inconsistency hurts everyone: askers can't know what's expected of them, answerers frequently get nailed for daring to answer a GMTC, and reviewers have to deal with audits that reinforce both contrary views (even after the audit is disputed).

I'm really looking for an answer from a diamond-mod here - everyone else has varying views on the topic.

### In Short:

**1)** Among questions that only contain "How do I do X?", what makes it "too broad" or "should be closed" vs. "leave open"? "It's subjective" isn't a good enough answer if we're going to be upholding audits in *both directions*, which we presently are.

**2)** What can be done to make the site's official stance, one way or the other, actually clear? Burying the stance exclusively in a meta post is a bad way of establishing enforced regulations. In the *very least*, [How to Ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and other help pages need to be updated to reflect the official stance, one way or the other.

Comment: For every close vote given, there always is a sucker who answers. And it needs 5 close votes but only [one sucker](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37002411/2564301).

Comment: I know that in practice, the continual answering of GMTCs is one of the reason we keep getting *more*. I think the hope of most 3k+ users is that closing GTMCs will prevent answering and discourage that type of unhealthy question. I'm in that camp too, but again, I don't mind changing my approach *if the site policy is made consistent.*

Comment: @gnat, I'm not asking for an interpretation of "too broad". I'm asking for a diamond-mod to state what makes a good GMTC vs. a bad one, since the meta-stance is to allow *some*.

Comment: this is what I read in your question: _what makes it "too broad, should be closed"_

Comment: @JasonMc92 the linked answer in your question is by a diamond mod...

Comment: I just can't see past the "T" in "GMTC" standing for "DA".

Comment: Yes, but as I said it does not clarify *where the line is*. And then, the issue that is being ignored is, the entire site precedence (and audit system!) is contrary. "Leave Open" on such a question will usually fail the audit.

Comment: It is very rarely that blunt.  Lots of HTWTC questions produce very popular Q+A.  A moderator will almost never help you dislike it.  Sub-categories are a copy/paste of a homework assignment.  And a less than half-assed functional spec.  Both are common enough to keep your vote button busy, "too broad" never fails to fit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not all "giv me da codez" questions are too broad.

For example, I could ask "How do I add two numbers in language X?" Assuming we're not talking about an esoteric language here, there is no language where this question is too broad.

With smaller questions, however, there is some chance that the question has been asked and answered before. The close reason there is "this is a duplicate".

If you do feel it is too broad, feel free to vote/flag how you want. When questions are too broad, it invites spam answers ("I have a library that does *exactly* what you want, <sub>and it's totally not malware!</sub>").

Comment: I wound up accepting this because (a) it is consistent with the diamond-mod stated perspective (in other convo), and (b) it answers the question clearly, without unnecessary asides.

Answer (score 16):

There is no close reason for, "user is asking for code".

Too Broad is not a euphemism for "user is asking for code".

There are lots of questions where someone is just asking for a bunch of code that will happen to have problems with them that *are* close reasons.  They're *correlated*, but that doesn't mean that you're closing them *because* they're asking for code.  If someone is asking you to write a database engine then the scope of that is clearly going to be beyond what you could post in an SO answer; if they're asking how to add two numbers together then the answer to that can be provided within a reasonably scoped answer.  Requirements dumps are often *correlated* with other problems as well, such as not providing enough information to be answerable, but if they have those problems then you're closing them *because of those problems* but not because they're a requirements dump.

This is what you'll be seeing throughout most all of the site's guidelines, and the more detailed meta posts *including the one that you specifically linked to*.  It went out of its way to say that you *shouldn't* just automatically close all requirements dumps.  It opens with, "There has never been a valid close reason for someone who didn't exhibit any research effort."

Yes, there may be occasional times where a comment or shorter answer won't emphasize the point and discuss the nuance to the degree that *the question you specifically quoted* does, and there is even an occasional meta user like yourself that has actually mis-interpreted those guidelines as meaning that you should just automatically close questions for not putting in effort, but that is not, nor has it ever been, the site's policy.

> Among questions that only contain "How do I do X?", what makes it "too broad, should be closed" vs. "leave open"?

You should be asking yourself if the question is *actually* very broad.  Consider how long a *complete* answer to the question would actually need to be.  if it'd be a few paragraphs plus a handful of lines of code, the question isn't too broad, if it'd take several pages of text and/or several screens of code, then it would be.  It has nothing to do with whether or not the OP just gave a requirements dump vs it being a long and detailed question.

> 2) What can be done to make the site's official stance, one way or the other, actually clear?

I'd say it is reasonably clear on this point.  You seemed to think that the guidelines on how to handle the question were just a euphemism for questions you don't like, are poorly researched, etc., when in actuality the guidelines for when to use the close reason are *exactly what the close reason actually says*.

Comment: That would be nice in theory if the answer I linked to didn't actually uphold two single-sentence "requirement dumps" as "good."

Comment: @JasonMc92 But they *didn't* say they were good questions.  They said they *didn't merit closure*.  Those are two radically different things.  Whether a question merits closure and whether or not it's a quality question are orthogonal (albeit correlated with each other).

Comment: @JasonMc92 "good" has nothing to do with it.  Use downvotes for "bad".  Closeworthy questions are not the same as downvotable ones.

Comment: As to (2), nope, I misunderstood nothing. Again, the audit system is actually forcing the *opposite behavior*.

Comment: I know full well that "Too Broad" isn't a eupahmism for "not well researched". What is means is, like many GMTC questions, there are too many answers for our format. For almost any coding challenge, there are *too many answers*. That's a 1-to-1 match, regardless of research effort.

Comment: @JasonMc92 No, you simply voted to close a bad question *that didn't actually meet any closure criteria* because you didn't like it, and choose a close reason that very clearly doesn't apply to it.  You were the one abusing the close feature, and the audit called out out on it.  When you vote to close questions because they actually meet the closure criteria for the reason you're choosing, then that'd be quite different.

Comment: Again, to be *very* clear, I don't mind leaving GMTCs open. What I mind is that *the entire audit system encourages the opposite behavior.* The audit system actually *trained* that response in me (and hundreds of reviewers), which is why I believed it to be too broad.

Comment: @JasonMc92 No, you cannot globally state, in the general case, that just because a question is asking for code that it is too broad.  Many of them will happen to be, but many of them *won't* be.  You need to analyze each individual question in turn and determine what the scope of a complete answer to the question would need to be.  You appear to not be doing that, hence why you're running into problems.

Comment: @JasonMc92 The audit system has trained you that automatically voting to close questions just for asking for code isn't appropriate.  And it is quite correct to do so.  You should be voting to close questions *because they meet the closure criteria*, and not because they're asking for code.  When you try to close questions that don't meet any closure criteria, you'll run into problems, as you have seen.

Comment: @Servy, I *do* that. This is not about one audit, it's about an entire system that has equated three-line GMTCs with "too broad". (I've only ever missed one audit on that, the one you're referencing being the first.) The one audit isn't the issue. It's *all the others* to the opposite.

Comment: So, if there is actually some further distinction, then that needs to be outlined, because *as my question states*, there is no such distinction to be found. Given two "How do I do X? Thx," one is "too broad", the other is not - **in audits**.

Comment: @JasonMc92 No, the entire system *hasn't* equated all requests for code as being Too Broad.  That is your false assumption.  if you happen to see someone else making that same mistake, feel free to correct them or refer them to an appropriate resources on Meta.  Of course, as I've said, while questions don't merit closure just because they're asking for code, many requirement dumps will happen to merit closure; the two are strongly correlated, so the fact that many of these types of questions that you've seen get closed is not surprising, but you're mistaken as to the *reason* they're closed.

Comment: @JasonMc92 Yes, it's entirely possible for one, "How do I do X"  question to be open, and for another to be closed as Too Broad, based on the scope of what it takes to describe how to do X.  That's the whole point, not all "how do I do X" questions need to be either open or closed, some will merit closure for some reason, and some won't, depending on the specifics.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion. I still need to hear from a diamond moderator, as there are equally-reputable users who take the opposite stance in practice. However, if you are correct, and "too broad" is entirely subjective, then **"too broad" closed questions need to be entirely expunged from the audit system**, because the fact of the matter is, the audits are therefore training both responses based on subjective judgments and differing opinions. (I didn't used to close vote GMTC until after several audits and a lot of precedence to that effect.) Do you see what I'm getting at now?

Comment: @JasonMc92 You linked to a diamond moderator saying the exact same thing in your question. That said, if you don't want responses from the community, then don't post on meta, because that's what this site is for.  Yes, question closure has a degree of subjectivity to it. That is unavoidable.  *All* close reasons have a degree of subjectivity to them, not just Too Broad. There are some questions that clearly and objectively meet a given closure criteria, but there will be many that aren't as clear.  That audits (and other systems) help to teach users what the community values are is *intended*.

Comment: Servy, community feedback is fine, but I'm not "accepting" until there's *official* word. Do you know of another way to get a public response from a diamond mod? Plus, for the *fifth* time, the linked answer did not answer my question (yours really didn't either until about the third edit). BTW, not all close votes are entirely subjective - a request for debugging help with no stated error or MCVE is veritably close-vote-worthy (another topic), and therefore safe to use in Audit.

Comment: @JasonMc92 The fact that you don't like the answer, and are upset that the site works differently than you want it to work, doesn't make it not an answer to your question.  There are means by which you can contact a moderator privately (chat, for example).  Yes, as I said in my comment, there will be some cases where it's objectively clear that a given close reason applies (either positively or negatively), but there will also be many cases where it won't, for every close reason.

Comment: @JasonMc92 I don't *care* if you're not going to accept my answer just because I'm not a mod.  Acceptance means virtually nothing at all on meta.  Why you'd decide whether or not to accept an answer based on who the author is, rather than the content of the answer, is rather unusual, but you can accept whatever you want to accept; nobody else can stop you anyway.

Comment: @JasonMc92 What exactly doesn't this answer or  the linked answer provide that you're after... I'm not quite following (probably comment overload)... As this answer, Laurel's answer and George's answer all look to contain the information I *think* you're asking for

Comment: Hi @JonClements, in case my question got lost in the noise (likely): (1) since audits on short, GMTC questions go both ways - "Too Broad" and "Leave Open" (thereby making it impossible to have consistent behavior), I needed to know what made one "broad" and the other "not broad". That was finally answered in Servy's question (which I did say), but I needed confirmed by a diamond-mod. The original answer I linked to didn't make that distinction clear.

Comment: (2): Given that (apparently from this answer), "Too Broad" is subjective, what can be done about the contrary review audits? Again, there are audits going *in both directions*, with the majority going towards closing all GMTCs as "too broad", and thereby prompting reviewers such as myself to change behavior (which I did) to doing the same. I propose that, if "Too Broad" really is this subjective, that a question closed as such would be omitted from the audit algorithm entirely.

Comment: @servy, I never said I "didn't like your answer", but (see B), it was incomplete, and I needed confirmation on (B) from a diamond mod.

Comment: @JasonMc92  Best practices for selecting a closing reason are come to through community consensus, and diamond mods are re-elected periodically.  They are no more the "official word" on these issues than you or I are.

Comment: @JasonMc92 (1) Good - 'cos I like Servy's answer and they're an active and informed member of the community; (2) It might be an idea to amalgamate a proposed-faq from existings posts if someone wants to volunteer - although, of course, that doesn't mean the people that should read it will. What with robo-reviewers, mis-clicks and what-not, audits aren't perfect anyway - it's not common it happens, but some audits can only be passed by taking the opposite action to what you'd expect - and that's not just for too broad but across the spectrum of other reasons -- that's another discussion though!

Comment: @JasonMc92 I've noticed that questions asked by users with an even number of characters in their name are sometimes closed as Too Broad, and they're sometimes not.  Given this, how can one possibly determine whether or not a question is Too Broad, given these conflicting audit cases?  That's literally the argument that you're making.  as you've been told *many* times now, the fact that a question is asking for code has nothing to do with whether or not it's Too Broad, whether its too broad or not is how you determine if it's Too Broad.

Comment: @Servy, I'm sorry, but think you've missed the point of my question about a dozen times now. You have pre-labeled me somehow as looking for justification for a wanton misinterpretation of "Too Broad", although I keep saying that's not the case. I am fine with either way, but the inconsistent audits on **identically-worded GMTCs** and the lack of help-doc info were the other issue, and I wanted those to be made consistent with *whichever* stance is official. **The present state of the audit system on the topic is contradictory to both stances.** It isn't the strawman argument you're making it.

Comment: @JonClements. I appreciate the feedback. I still wonder if we need to remove "too broad" closed questions as candidates for audit, simply since they are so subjective and inconsistent in situations like what I described. That was half the conversation I was *trying* to start here...should I start yet another question to that effect, or is that (as I'd guess) a waste of time?

Comment: @JasonMc92 You have provided no examples of identically worded questions treated differently.  You've said that code request questions aren't closed consistently, as is exactly what one would expect to be the case.  You've provided nothing to indicate that questions that actually meet closure criteria *aren't* being handled consistently.  Of course, even though you haven't done so, I've already stated that closure can be subjective, and different people can and do disagree on whether a particular post merits closure.

Comment: @Servey, and as I said, if it is so subjective as you say, using my those for audit is questionably reliable. We're going in circles, and I'm not saying anything new. I'm done.

Comment: @JasonMc92 If you're uncomfortable with the fact that question closures are going to have some level of subjectivity then you shouldn't be reviewing.  It's inherent in the system.  Answering programming questions is [largely] objective, but moderating content simply isn't.  There's no way to have audits that *aren't* going to have a degree of subjectivity, at least some of the time (at least not if they're going to be effective).