# Are ugly questions that don't fall into any of the "close" reasons strictly ineligible for close votes?

Tags: support

Questions like this have no corresponding "close" reason.

1. What is an "int"?
2. How do I add two numbers
3. How can I make this code that I found do what I want
4. Please show me how to write this C program in Lua

What I have read tells me that I may only down vote them.

Is this strictly true, or is the common practice of squeezing a question into a reason for closure that it doesn't really fit officially permitted?

I am anxious to follow the rules rather than simply copy popular behaviour.

Comment: 1 and 2 are surely dupes, 4 is too broad, 3 might actually be on topic if they give a MCVE.

Comment: And without MCVE we have an off-topic subreason for that ...

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thank you, that helps. I've made it a numbered list to clarify your comment. I shall look for more examples, but I hoped that you would understand the *spirit* of the question. At some point there were no dupes; would *those* questions be ineligible for close votes? The point of #3 is that it has no MCVE (this is the entire content of all of the questions). I disagree that #4 is too broad. I may be a single statement.

Comment: I think 1 and 2 are too-broad or unclear. Maybe with a language tag they would be on-topic but likely a dupe.

Comment: Well the spirit of the question is *"amirite?!"* so I left it alone. If the first two questions were asked at a point where that information wasn't already on SO, maybe they would be OK. If you don't think the close reasons apply to a given question, don't vote to close it. "Ugliness" alone certainly doesn't rate closure.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I'm asking how flexible the close reasons are. They have been [deliberately trimmed in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) to prohibit close votes for questions that are lazy or foolish, and I wanted to clarify things.

Comment: You asked 14 questions and answered more than 4000. You're obviously **highly** intelligent. How is it possible that you don't understand the rules/guidelines of this website?

Comment: @AlonEitan: I can assure you that I'm not alone. Everyone on the site that I speak to on a casual basis is similarly baffled. If you *do* understand how the site works then I would encourage you to post an answer.

Comment: @AlonEitan: As **gnat** wrote in a recent thread, *"the very fact that so many voters find it difficult to apply is the problem. To learn how to close standard, blatant, routine garbage one has to look for obscure explanation at meta? give me a break. Approach like this in practice means vast majority of 30 thousands close voters won't know how to close trash"*

Comment: @Borodin: who do you speak to on a casual basis that is *a regular on Stack Overflow*? I don't know that many people in my wider circle of acquaintances that are regulars on SO. Those that are, are not baffled. So now we have two anecdotal straw polls of people we spoke to, who is right? And take into account that people you speak to may have their own agendas, I know gnat certainly has one.

Comment: @Borodin: but we have another data point; the voting on your Meta posts. It seems that on the whole, Meta visitors disagree with your discussion points.

Comment: @Borosin I'm still learning like you :) I just keep reminding myself that I'm interacting with humans with feelings and try to act accordingly. I see it moe as general guidlines rather than stricted rules

Comment: @Borodin All of your examples could be closed as _too broad_.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this strictly true, or is the common practice of squeezing a
>   question into a reason for closure that it doesn't really fit
>   officially permitted?

I don't think it's "officially permitted" as much as you're usually not going to get caught doing this to new users. Brand new users don't have enough rep to ask about their question on Meta and fairly new users with a little rep often don't know how to contest decisions here. An experienced user might complain but they'd be wary of the Meta effect.

My understanding of the official position is that not all bad questions are also off topic. (Much like not all bad answers are Not an Answer.)

But I'd argue that your comment on your previous question:

> ...in the mean time people generally use Questions seeking debugging help must ..., too broad, or unclear, none of which are properly appropriate.

isn't actually true. A lot of questions that simply ask for code are actually closeable for those reasons. For example, your #2. What does the asker mean by "number"? An int? A float? A numeric value in a string? In a PDF? An image?

I guarantee you, if you try to answer a question that vague the OP is going to comment on your answer about how it doesn't work for them because [situation they didn't feel like explaining in their question but assumed you'd know anyway]. It is Unclear, no squeezing needed.