# Is "how can I do X with language Y?" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

Are questions of the form "how can I do X with language Y?" off-topic or on-topic when the standard toolchain for language Y has a (possibly obscure) flag or option for doing exactly X?  If not, is there a standard way of reopening such questions that were closed as off-topic by users presumably ignorant of the standard toolchain?

The concrete question I have in mind here is [How do I generate LaTeX from Isabelle/HOL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421234/how-do-i-generate-latex-from-isabelle-hol) (to which the appropriate answer is roughly "invoke `isabelle build -d` after setting up your project in this way"), and other examples would include "how can I generate assembly from C/C++ source?", "is it possible to get a version of a C source file with all `#include`s inlined?", "[how] can I run Perl code from the shell without making a source file?", "can I autogenerate HTML documentation of Java APIs for my own code that's like the standard library documentation?", "is there a standard 'javadoc for Python' that produces HTML documentation?"

Comment: "How can I do X?" is one style of on-topic question. "How can I do X with Y" is the same thing as a "How can I do X?" question. Now ultimately each question is still subject to the rest of the closure criteria and no question is explicitly on-topic _just_ because it asks how to do a thing. If it is too broad, unclear, primarily opinion based, general computing, server administration, etc, then it should be closed. See also: [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for “How do I do X?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253069)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Though it doesn't answer "what's the standard way to get a particular question reopened/reclassified if the close reason is incorrect?"  Do I ask a new question specifically for that? It seems like the close reason for the Isabelle question was "the asker isn't providing proof of effort", though there seems to be a bit of a culture war between those who think that people who don't do enough research need to be punished, and those who think it's a way of saying "I don't know how to help you, please tell me where to start".  But it seems like then you downvote, not close?

Comment: See: [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)

Answer (score -2):

All of the questions you have listed are either people asking for someone to write their code for them, or recommend a library to them. So I would say there is very little chance these questions are on topic.