# Add "I'm new, please tell me how to do X" to the don't-ask help page

Tags: feature-request, help-center

From time to time there are questions which follow the scheme: *I have 0 experience in language X. How to solve task Y in that language?*

Today I stumbled upon such a question again. I close-voted it as *too broad*, commented that such questions shouldn't be asked and wanted to additionally add a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. But after reading that help page I have the feeling that it isn't clear enough about that, especially for new users.

Can we add this explicitly to the above mentioned help page?

---

Update: It is not the text phrase *I'm new* which I'm concerned about; I'm concerned because such questions are typically too broad and don't show any own, reasonable coding efforts.

Comment: This sets the expectations right: SO is the worst place to have 1-on-1 learning experience. You can learn something, but that's for your own effort assimilating the information. Its purpose isn't that.

Comment: but... [*How do i do X* is explicitly on topic.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) Such questions *are* how do i do x questions. You can certainly downvote them if they're unclear/lowquality/poorly researched, close if they're too broad or off topic due to not having enough information or not being specific enough, but "how do i do x" isn't *always* off topic or too broad.

Comment: Of course is *How do I X* not off-topic. I wasn't saying that. I'm talking about *How do I get task Y done in language X without knowing that language*. That's at least too broad plus it doesn't show any code. Meaning it _does_ clearly fit multiple off-topic criterias

Comment: Is the *"without knowing that language"* part what bothers you about these questions? That's just noise that needs to be edited out, along with *"Thank you"* and *"Please Help"*

Comment: It's the too broad and no code part which bothers me. Also I personally think this is not the right approach to start with a new language. (And I don't want to work in a company where people are doing that.) .. But it's not something I'm extremely concerned about. I'm just asking :)

Comment: [**Only debugging questions explicitly require code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281)

Comment: There's something related in help/on-topic which can possibly be modified (and kept where it is): "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it". This needn't apply to homework only... and the current phrasing allows for "I haven't done anything yet", so we should probably add something about "a reasonable attempt" in there.

Comment: @KevinB Granted it's noise, such wording usually serves as self-apologetic "don't judge" -disclaimer. Bothersome is it demonstrates awareness of rules not followed.

Comment: @Dukeling but attempts are not required

Comment: @TinyGiant Agree to disagree.

Comment: @Dukeling how can an attempt be required if only debugging questions explicitly require code, and a large portion of the most useful questions on Stack Overflow contain no code at all?

Comment: @TinyGiant The whole point of this post is to *make* something explicit. The question is what that is - most people agree that "please write code for me, here are some requirements" is off topic, so how do we tell people that (apart from closing their question as too broad and downvoting it into oblivion)? Also, research attempts don't have to be code.

Comment: @Dukeling I don't agree that such questions have ever been inherently off-topic. I would say that such questions may or may not be too broad, unclear, or primarily opinion based depending on the question asked, but saying that they are inherently off-topic would be a disservice to the community.

Comment: Largely what people dislike about such questions is when they ask too much (too broad), are vague or missing details neccessary to answer (unclear), or it's already been asked and answered many times before (duplicate). Notice that all of these are already reasons to close a question, with specific guidance that is useful to the question, not a nonsensical "We don't accept how-to questions, sorry".

Comment: @Dukeling Many of the top 50 questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes look to me like they fit the paradigm of "please write code for me, here are some requirements". (If you count writing a Git command as writing code, then make that a *majority* of those questions.) Do you actually think most of them deserve closure? That they deserve an exception from the rules? Or that I am misinterpreting what *"please write code for me, here are some requirements"* means? The latter would be most interesting, since it lets us drill into what sort of question you *really* object to.

Comment: You could always link to [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236), which is kind of the canonical post for unanswerable "gimme teh codez" questions.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's true, but "gimme teh codez" is absolutely a reason to downvote and vote to close. We really don't want low-quality questions like that to proliferate on the network because it diminishes the usefulness of the site to people who have real questions that they actually put effort into.

Comment: @EJoshua no that is the canonical for why asking "Can someone help me?" is not an answerable question. That has nothing to do with how-to questions that don't contain code. There is no "gimme teh codez" close reason, never has been. If you feel like downvoting such questions, so be it. There's no all-encompassing "this question asks for code" close reason.

Comment: @TinyGiant I was going to reply in the same way, but then saw that the Q's author commented that it is *"intended to apply to pretty much any "requirements only" question"*. I think it's a confused question (the title and the description in the comments don't cohere) and answer (*"How do I convert a string to a number?"* is good but asking *"how to implement something"* is bad and not a "programming question"? That's nonsense; the former, apparently good, question is an *example* of the latter, apparently bad, category), but it does (in parts, schizophrenically) say what EJoshuaS says it does.

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree that there's no requirement that a question contain code, or even that the question has to be *about* code (it could be about an algorithm or a question about a programming tool, for example). Technically, "gimme teh codez" *does* make homework questions off-topic, but even apart from that these questions are almost always too broad or unclear.

Comment: Homework questions are treated as any other question. The idea that they should be treated differently is mostly propaganda meant to say "We apply the normal rules, we just inherently don't like these questions so we're going to be more liberal with our application of the rules." The rules that are violated don't change because the question lists requirements or is a copy-paste of a homework problem, so our guidance and close votes shouldn't either. Use the actual close reason that applies and avoid handwaving and over-generalization.

Comment: @TinyGiant "such questions may ... be too broad, unclear, or primarily opinion based" - close enough (for me there has never really been a clear distinction between those and off-topic). It does a bigger disservice to the community to pretend that such questions are fine up to the point where they actually appear on the site. Although most people asking such questions arguably wouldn't be dissuaded by much from asking their question as is.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm talking about questions that post a bunch of requirements (typically a copy-paste of homework or a programming contest question) and then ask some version of "please give me code". "How do I do a thing" is not "a bunch of requirements".

Comment: @Dukeling then maybe you might be better served by referring to such questions as overly broad how-to questions instead of "gimme teh codez" or "please write code for me, here are some requirements" as being inspecific and vague while discussing moderation can only ever lead to confusion and people reading things out of what you write that you did not intend them to read. My point entirely is that specific guidance is much more helpful than over-generalization, hand-waving, and vague statements, so we should provide specific guidance and use specific close reasons.

Comment: @MarkAmery As the author of the post in question, I can confirm that I intended the scope to be a bit broader than including the words "Can someone help me" There's a big distinction between "How do I implement this feature" and "How do I do a specific programming task".

Comment: How is that page discovered? I didn't know about its existence until reading this question!!

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was about to link to that page in a comment. It would be discovered by clicking on that link. The problem was that I felt it won't be clear to the user why their question shouldn't be asked from reading that page.

Comment: I think what this question is really asking for is that the Help should emphasize that you're expected to have enough expertise in the technology you're working with that you don't need to receive a one hour one-on-one tutorial to work through every last detail of the solution. You need to know enough to be able to take an answer and work with it on your own time. But the thing this specifically asks for probably won't accomplish that, and I don't really recommend editing this question drastically enough to get at that. That said, I doubt SO would be willing to make any such change.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Attempts *are* required for homework questions, especially for things that are trivial and / or uninteresting for people that already know the language or understand computer programming in general.  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).  What makes questions like this "too broad" is that they're implicitly asking for an explanation / tutorial of *why* this is the answer, and potentially huge amounts of background knowledge required to understand the answer.

Comment: @Peter Homework questions are treated as any other question. The idea that they should be treated differently is mostly propaganda meant to say "We apply the normal rules, we just inherently don't like these questions so we're going to be more liberal with our application of the rules." The rules that are violated don't change because the question lists requirements or is a copy-paste of a homework problem, so our guidance and close votes shouldn't either. Use the actual close reason that applies and avoid handwaving and over-generalization.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Agreed.  The only option for not being downvoted as "not useful" due to triviality and being over-broad (which part of the problem are you asking about: an implicit "teach me x86 asm" is too broad) is to make an attempt so answerers can see where you're stuck.  If one part of your homework really does make a useful Q&A, then sure.  I posted an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/359604#359604) on that meta Q&A.  I'm not sure I still agree with what I wrote then, but I haven't up or down voted the main answer there.

Comment: @TinyGiant My problem with homework questions is that they often include arbitrary useless restrictions with no concrete reason behind them besides "the instructor told me".  I mean, "write a matrix type without using and std types" is dumb because the right thing to do is "write something equivalent to the std type" then "write the matrix type", but is ruled out by arbitrary homework-esque rules.  "I'm on embedded I don't have std" is a practical restriction, "I cannot use std::vector because my instructor said so" isn't.  And as arbitrary restrictions lead to bad answers for general users.

Comment: @Yakk if the requirements are clear and don't make the question too broad, then it doesn't matter if you don't _like_ the requirements. That's like saying because I don't like Angular, I should be able to close all questions where the use of Angular is a requirement.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, because more than half of the purpose of SO is to help the next person who finds the question.  And artificial impractical requirements (as arbitrary assignment requirements tend to be) restrict the answer to being useless to another person at best, and more often harmful (because the answer is something *nobody should write* without those *specific requirements* which come from that *specific assignment*).  Maybe "too narrow" is the right close reason; unlikely to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: @TinyGiant "The code must consist of only the letters a through z in alphabetical order with whitespace and non-letters added at will" is a fundamentally different kind of restriction than "I have to use Angular".  And homework restrictions are far, far closer to "a through z" than they are to "use Angular".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Too many requirements is a qualifier for Too Broad.  They must ask how to do one thing (or possibly two closely linked things) clearly. That said, if the requirement doesn't make the question too broad, then it's just a reason to downvote (this is not useful).

Answer (score 23):

The thing is that the "don't ask" page has largely become bastardized and abandoned across the network.  By convention, the place where you should look to see what *isn't* on-topic is actually [at the "do ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of the Help Center.

Now, the issue of adding it there - would it *realistically* make a difference?  Or do we want some wording we can use as a shield when people inevitably throw rocks our way about this?  Would it be better or worse to just close these questions as "too broad" and just leave it at that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm personally looking for something to point new users towards which they can understand. Probably I'm too naive but my hope is that it would realistically make a difference. That's why I was asking :) I'm thinking that because I've seen many of such questions which seem to have been asked in good faith. But yeah, I can't estimate how big the difference would be if we add that.

Comment: Yeah, but this ain't a new endeavor.  We've been gunning to try and get more information in front of new users for *years* now, and time has proven more often than not, people just don't read the Help Center in nearly the same volume we expect.

Comment: I see. (and not being super surprised :) ) Well, I think adding one little sentence might still not hurt - _if we want that_

Comment: I mean for the most part I'm a hard-and-fast "no" on this one.  I just don't see what doing this would get us that closing and walking away wouldn't.  I *really* want you to try and sell this to me since I could be convinced, I just need to be convinced...

Comment: Well, it's hard to convince you of the usefulness of adding a point to that page since you not seem to be convinced of the usefulness of that page at all. My argument is that even if users have been asked such a question once, it is simpler and more streamlined for people like me to point them to the issue with their question. It makes our life easier and the reaction of the community to such questions more predictable and unique. Another few good guys will read it before they ask their question, step back and prepare a better question showing some basic knowledge and code. do it for them

Comment: If the "don't ask" is useless then why even have a "do ask" page. Quality control can only be achieved if the don'ts are more prominent than the dos. At this point just remove both let the shit-show continue to flow.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus:  I'd argue that the decision was made because the on-topic page was getting more traffic than the don't ask page.  It doesn't mean the don't ask page is any less bastardized; it just means that the information *is* getting to as many people as it can.  Removing both would be strongly counter to the goal of getting *some* information out there.

Comment: Another thing. I expect many to most users who ask such a question to act in good faith. They have their problem and they surely think that SO is their solution. To have a nicely phrased standard response makes it more unlikely for them to get an unfriendly response, get frustrated, feeling misunderstood and so on. It can help giving them a better user experience on SO. Also they would realize that they are treated equal like others and that their problem isn't something uncommon. I mean once you understood what's the problem, it's very unlikely to be still frustrated about those who pt it out

Comment: @hek2mgl if you want to prevent the frustration of people asking such questions, you should use the specific close reason that applies to the specific question. Nothing is more frustrating than over-generalization and hand-waving about how an entire category of on-topic questions is somehow off-topic.

Comment: The "on-topic" page already says that questions about "a specific programming problem" are on topic.  When we close a question as "too broad", we are saying that it does not meet that criterion in particular, and that none of the others apply.  The issue with that has always been interpreting the word "specific".  If we want to clarify there that "How to code task X in language Y?" is not on topic on its own, then that's where we need to make a change, but to my knowledge, we've never come up with any better wording.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "How to code task X in language Y?" Is not inherently off-topic.