# Question closers should have good reputation in the subject matter

Tags: discussion, feature-request

My question has recently been a subject of vitriolic discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23380294/366309

At this point, I concede that its original form had been lacking in detail.  At the same time, I think any more details I could add would further muddle the question (or I might add a picture which says exactly the same thing as what I described).  Some community members though have offered their assistance in improving the question.

With that out of the way, I want to bring up a serious issue with question closers. All 5 of the close-voters have ZERO reputation in the vim, vimscript, and syntax-highlighting tags. It's not a surprise that they cannot understand the question given its sparse details.

I would expect a Vim expert to recall a time when he was in my shoes as a noob and then try to help.  I was told that it was not clear what my knowledge of vimscript was, but for me, some applicable vim code would help, and it would be my responsibility to find out how to apply it (How to write it in `.vimrc`? How to load as a plugin? I can do my research on that.)

[image]

### Proposed solution:

Close-voters should have sufficient (I do not know how to define this) reputation on the subject matter.

Answer (score 7):

No.

> I'd like to highlight the enclosing parentheses whenever the cursor is inside them.  How do I do that in Vim?  Several plugins that I can google do not behave that way.

- Too broad
- Not enough detail - Unclear
- Didn't try anything - Downvotes

It isn't very hard for most people to see that. If you have 3k reputation, you probably can tell whether a question is obviously bad.

Anyway, your edits *did* improve the question a bit. Keep going, then it will be fit for the site. If you edit within the 5 day "on hold" window, it'll be put in the reopen queue.

Comment: Valid point.  Note though that they're not my edits, they're the first answerer's (Ben's) edits.  He has 90 votes in vim, and he opened up new avenues for my research.  If people with zero reputation closed the question, it may not have reached the vim experts who could understand.  I am not trying to defend only my question, but also those who honestly struggle to explain their problem (though it is difficult to distinguish them from the lazy homework-type ones).  Still, I stand by my proposal to let high-rep-in-tag users have more authority to close questions.

Comment: As I said, it is not hard to decide on whether to closing questions in any language. I just named three points, which 11 people agree on given the three closings.

Comment: And there are 5 upvotes on the first answer. Plus 9 upvotes and 3 stars (stars are not necessarily positive marks of course) on the question.  Clearly several noobs have found it helpful the way it is.  When I asked the question, I did not find duplicates.  In analogy to the research world, it may have been a new frontier.  And we don't have many words for things we observe in new frontiers.

Comment: Maybe it's a good question. But it's definitely off-topic for this site.

Comment: No it is not off-topic. That has been already discussed and I will not repeat it here.

Comment: You can debate it all you want, but the fact is that it's been closed three times.

Comment: And the fact is that this stirred confusion among mods http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253057/366309

Comment: 15 for, 1 against. I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: That's true.  I would have rather have it that if at least one noob found a question or answer helpful, versus 99 other experts arguing against it based on semantics (rather than based on hard technical correctness), then I think it deserves a place.  But maybe SO really is becoming more elitist and less friendly to noobs (not just my words, but also from what I have read outside SO circles).

Comment: This is a strict site. There are great questions that *just don't belong here*.

Comment: Not every noob has the luxury of a teammate to ask beside his desk, and his only resort is to ask humans on the other side of the world through SO.  SO was a welcoming respite from the snarky linux forums, and I see it turning into those forums.  If that is the attitude that SO wishes to adopt towards future technologists, good luck.  Enjoy the echo chamber.

Comment: Hey, if you want to change something feature-requesting is the way to go, not comments.

Comment: I'm still commenting because I believe SO has a chance to be better. And my question was tagged feature-request, yes?

Comment: You are talking about things much outside of the original feature-request's scope.

Comment: Because those things would be classified as too broad.  The original post was a proposed concrete action towards that.

Comment: No, the original post was about restricting downvotes - that has nothing to do with removing the "too broad" close reason.