# Why are the questions closed

Tags: discussion

I am observing that StackOverflow moderators are marking every other question as opinion and closing them because they are opinionated.

I don't understand this. Everything in the world is perspective and opinion these days. Days of Black and White question and answers are gone.

Today if I start to build a new out of the box software, I need expert's opinions and approaches. And that is what the platform of stackOverflow was in the early days. It seems to be losing it's charm these days.

When we need a helping hand, you are only one of the few we can reach out to. This is the only place we all come down to. We are not going to hold stackOverflow as criminal if my application crashes because of an opinion. We understand it's an opinion and we will ultimately take the decision to follow/ unfollow it

Please don't close the questions just because it asks for opinions. Let people talk to themselves as much as they can. PLEASE!!!

Comment: Yub, sorry, this belongs in meta.

Comment: `Days of Black and White question and answers are gone.` Yes you are true. `Be specific on your questions`.

Comment: You might want to check if there is a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) that is open for these kind of questions but it differs per room...

Answer (score 10):

Take a look around on Meta, this has been discussed ad nauseam in the last five years. See e.g. [Opinionated programming answers are prohibited?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253055)

The bottom line is the community doesn't want opinion-based questions because they tend not to work in the Q&A format: they'd generate chatter, spam, and low-quality contributions. The focus of SO has become narrower and narrower over time, more and more focused on precisely answerable technical questions.

There was the attempt to outsource those questions to a new web site, [Programmers Stack Exchange.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) but even that didn't work  as the new community saw it necessary to raise its standards [and reject much of the opinion-based content coming in from Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382)

I agree it is a pity - it *would* be cool to have a place to discuss design decisions and such with the world's best programmers, to see why they prefer one framework over another, etc.

But it's the way it is, it wasn't for lack of trying that this didn't work out.

Comment: lol 'Everything in the world is perspective and opinion these days' - my compiler begs to differ, also any scientist I've ever met:)

Comment: @Martin but what if, say, the laws of gravity would turn out to be socially constructed to disfavour overweight people - a huge proportion of which are also poor? Critical research is needed

Comment: @Pekka웃 Wait... Social engineering made by whoever created this universe? You're pushing conspiracy theories to a whole new level my friend... I like it!

Answer (score 5):

The reason Stack Overflow has been so useful and become so popular is that it matches precise technical questions with precise technical answers. If it had always welcomed requests for comment or solicitations of opinion and philosophy then it would not have become even a quarter as useful a resource as it is now.

There are plenty of discussion forums that will welcome such opinion-based threads, but you'll find that a lot of serious programmers avoid such places exactly because they turn into a hotbed of pointless argument.

The concentration of technical knowledge undoubtedly makes it tempting to ask for thoughts and opinions from the crowd here, but allowing such a change of nature would ruin what makes Stack Overflow so valuable.

Comment: After receiving mail from customer support, I requested to change question state from Closed to Open and moderators deleted the question itself. What is the problem in keeping the question in "closed" state? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611066/java-and-javascriptjs-features-confusion-in-understanding-6-overlapping-feat

Comment: there may be 6 questions but if someone apply common sense by going through them, they are fundamentals and basics. Since I posted a question on meta to re-open, the question is deleted since moderators got annoyed. There are no other reasons why this question should not be in open or close state

Comment: @sunrise the question wasn't deleted by a moderator but by regular users. For blatantly off-topic questions deletion is the standard action. It's also something that we've had a lot of discussion about over the past four years