# What is the point of closing questions for details and clarity, debugging details, needs more focus, or very low quality?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

While I scroll through questions, I see that some of them are commonly closed. The common reasons for closure are **needs details and clarity, needs debugging details, needs more focus, or very low quality** (and for duplicates, but I agree with that one). But, what's the point if we can provide a more descriptive comment that will actually guide them to helpful links? For example, I have a .txt file on my desktop with the following contents:

> Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Of course, I delete certain parts as required, such as Welcome or links that are useless to them (like if the question is good but the code is excessive, then I'll delete How do I ask a good question and take the tour).

I've never had any of my questions closed for these reasons (except for a duplicate) but some did not meet requirements like being a good question. If you decide to take a scroll through my profile, note that I edited my old questions, which turned out to be a waste of time.

Also, the questions get closed very quickly. I see the question was posted about a minute ago, and **bam**, before someone even read through the whole question, it's closed. Why would you close it and ruin the OP's ego when you could simply direct them to link?

> Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

If you don't feel like finding the link, then just say "You need to add details and clarify the problem" or whatever the question needs. If OP adds whatever it needs, it's probably a struggle for it to reopen and for someone to find it again.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354342/hello-everyone-i-want-to-ask-how-can-i-make-the-new-data-come-before-the-foote) was a pretty bad question. As soon as I openened it, it was closed. Sure, the question was short, but when I opened there were 2 downvotes and it's closed. Without a comment. Of course, people later commented, but it would've been helpful to comment and *then* downvote or flag.

Another reason to not close the question would be that **others might be able to understand**. If someone else understands, they'll answer. They can't answer if it's closed. They too would have to wait for the question to be reopened, if ever.

If the question is low quality, then just guide OP on how to edit and format a question.

Of course, there are times when a question does need to be closed and maybe even deleted. But why would someone delete a question if it needs details and clarity, needs debugging details, needs more focus, or is just very low quality?

Comment: *"If someone else understands, they'll answer"* Yeah, and we don't want that. This is why we close questions. They need to be clear enough to be helpful to other people finding them in the future.

Comment: The duplicate closure banner is the comment that is guiding them to what they need to do to improve the questions. At least that is what the banner is meant to do. The author sees a special message.

Comment: I think there are some meta posts regarding this. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303197/why-are-the-questions-closed

Comment: @Dharman Op is talking about the other types of closure.

Comment: A closed question is pulled off the question list, giving it time to be fixed rather than continuing to attract downvotes.

Comment: Not really. I think the answer is "because that way the site is more useful, unlike yahoo answers and stuff"

Comment: @Dharman that's not my point. My point is to comment rather than close

Comment: I don't want to have any more of these discussions about more comments. We have too many comments already. If you want to help new users starting out then please suggest how to improve the existing closure comment to provide the user with more guidance. I would happily upvote such feature request, but not one that encourages more comments from normal users.

Comment: @KevinB Oh, that explains a bit more. I thought it just said closed and that's it.

Comment: @Rojo Yea, no, a closed question gets moved to the reopen queue when it is edited, closure doesn't have to be the end

Comment: _"The common reasons for closure are needs details and clarity, needs debugging details, needs more focus, or very low quality"_ That last one isn't a reason for closure.

Comment: Yes, VLQ is a flag, but that's a minor point.

Comment: @Rojo 'comment rather than close' would only work if we have a way to *chain* ppl to their questions and we forced them to edit them as they see comments. A lot of ppl push for comments over moderation. But the reality is that a lot of our traffic comes, asks one question, and leaves. Using comments over closure runs the risk of leaving opened "crap" on the site. If the user is active, a closed banner is as easy to remove as replying to a comment that points out something's lacking in your question. What would be the direct benefit, for the site, of comments over closure?

Comment: "The common reasons for closure are needs details and clarity, needs debugging details, needs more focus, **or very low quality**" there's no such standard close reason, so it has to be custom.

Comment: To answer the question formally present in the post "But why would someone delete a question if it needs details and clarity, needs debugging details, needs more focus, or is just very low quality?" - in 99% of cases OP shows no intention/desire to fix the post so the post follows the site's rules and simply deletes the post (whether to ask somewhere else or just repost again). In case of [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354342/hello-everyone-i-want-to-ask-how-can-i-make-the-new-data-come-before-the-foote) you used OP simply deleted post and not re-posted it.

Comment: @Rojo - Just so you know, instead of deleting that question, you should have improved it.  Now any user who downvoted it, cannot reverse their vote, even if they wanted to.  Deleted questions still count towards or against your ability to ask new questions so it's not a solution to any problem.

Comment: @SecurityHound I did not vote, close, delete, or comment on that post

Comment: @Rojo - It wasn’t even your question?  Well my advice is sound for whoever the author is, somebody who decided to delete their question, rather than improving the question and getting it reopened

Comment: To whoever marked this question as a duplicate... You're wrong. That post is about downvotes... This is about flagging...

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how the dupe answers this question in any way. [Why Do We Need to Close Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92580/165261) is a cross-site dupe, but unfortunately it's not here.

Comment: Separately, that comment you're leaving is really not at all descriptive. At least the close vote reasons say, specifically, what is wrong.

Comment: I'll often leave specific comments like `Your post lacks enough information to investigate the problem. It's hard to help with code issues without seeing the relevant parts of the code—a description of the code is usually not enough. To enable others to help you, include a [mre], along with the exact text of any error messages (including, for any exceptions, the full [stack trace](/a/23353174), as well as which line of code is producing it). For more advice, please see [ask].`  I've yet to see a generic one that does a good job of explaining what's wrong to a new user.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a help forum, it's a Q&A site. Its purpose is to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers. Questions and answers are not intended only for the benefit of the OP - they're intended for the benefit of anyone who ever has a similar problem (which just happens to include the OP).

Besides, Stack Overflow gets thousands of questions per day; it's hard enough to get attention for good questions without having to compete with questions where the OP put forth no effort to solve their problem or formulate their question properly. The question you link to is a perfect example - the poster clearly put forth virtually no effort to formulate their question properly, and its continued existence on the site distracts from legitimate questions.

That being said, not having question closure would be unfair to answerers who would be forced to wade through all of the garbage to find stuff to answer, it would be unfair to people who put in the effort to research their problem and formulate their question properly, and it would be unfair to future readers who are trying to find high-quality information. Quite simply, allowing questions like the ones you link to on the site would diminish the usefulness of the site for everyone.

Also, if you understand a question that was closed as unclear, please edit it so that it's more understandable to other people. There are also multiple lines of appeal if a question that was not, in fact, unclear was closed for being unclear; please feel free to use them if you feel that a question was closed in error.

See also: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: *"thousands of questions per day"*: It could be stated as "nearly 10,000 questions per day" (it is about 8,000 new questions on weekdays - now a total of [20,890,111 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)).